# Non-Unique/Duplicate Elements

Tags: code-golf, array, counting

Write a program which finds the non-unique elements of an array of signed integers. The resulting array can be in any order.

Your answer may be a snippet which assumes the input to be stored in a variable (`d`, say) and evaluates to the correct result.

#### Test Cases

Each test case is a single line in the format `input => output`. Note that other permutations of the output are valid as well.

```
[]                        => []
[-1, 0, 1]                => []
[1, 1]                    => [1]
[3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 3]  => [3, 0, 1]
[-34, 0, 1, -34, 4, 8, 4] => [-34, 4]
```

Order of the elements doesn't matter.

This is code golf, so the shortest answer (in bytes) wins.

Comment: [Related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/8669/21487)

Comment: since this is for array of integers code would be different. I think much shorter. That is for a string.

Comment: Are we allowed to accept input as lines instead of as an array? For example, instead of `[-1, 0, 1]`, can we input (replace \n with newlines): `"-1\n0\n1"`?

Comment: Does the output have to be a list or would a set be acceptable?

Comment: And does it have to output in that format?

Comment: Yes, the output needs to be an array, otherwise if iterable is allowed people would start producing `301` as results.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## [K5](http://johnearnest.github.io/ok/index.html), 5 bytes

Assuming the input is already in a variable called `d`,

```
?d^?d
```

Take the distinct elements (`?`) of d except (`d^`) the distinct elements of d (`?d`). Nicely symmetrical, no? This works because the "except" operator removes only the first occurrence of the right argument from the left argument.

More generally,

```
nu: {?x^?x}
```

In action:

```
  nu'(();-1 0 1;1 1;3 0 0 1 1 0 5 3;-34 0 1 -34 4 8 4)
(()
 ()
 ,1
 0 1 3
 -34 4)
```

### Edit:

If we wanted to preserve the order of the first occurrence of non-unique elements, we could reverse the source list before and after we remove the unique elements via except at the cost of 4 extra bytes:

```
  nu: {?|(|x)^?x}
  nu'(();-1 0 1;1 1;3 0 0 1 1 0 5 3;-34 0 1 -34 4 8 4)
(()
 ()
 ,1
 3 0 1
 -34 4)
```

Answer (score 10):

## CJam, 10

Assuming the array is already in variable D (based on [this comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60610/non-unique-elements/60612#comment145849_60613)):

```
D{De=(},_&
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=%5B-34%200%201%20-34%204%208%204%5D%3AD%3B%0AD%7BDe%3D(%7D%2C_%26)

**Explanation:**

```
D{…},   filter items of D based on the block
  De=   count occurrences in D
  (     decrement (resulting in true/false for duplicate/unique)
_&      remove duplicates from the results
```

Note: append a `p` if you want pretty printing, otherwise the resulting array is just printed out with no delimiters by default. That is acceptable since the question specifies the snippet only needs to "evaluate to the correct result".

### Standard input/output version, 13:

```
q~_{1$e=(},&p
```

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q~_%7B1%24e%3D(%7D%2C%26p&input=%5B-34%200%201%20-34%204%208%204%5D)

**Explanation:**

```
q~      read and evaluate the input array
_       duplicate the array
{…},    filter items based on the block
  1$    copy the array
  e=    count occurrences
  (     decrement (resulting in true/false for duplicate/unique)
&       set intersection with the initial array (removes duplicates)
p       pretty print
```

Comment: 13: `q~$e\`{((<~}%p`

Comment: @Sp3000 I found another 13-byte version before reading your comment :) It preserves the order too.

Answer (score 9):

### Haskell - 32

```
import Data.List;f l=nub$l\\nub l
```

Pretty short, even with the import. `a \\ b` removes the first occurrence of each element of `b` from `a`, and `nub` makes all elements of a list unique.

Answer (score 7):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
S{.-Q{Q
```

[Try it online.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=S%7B.-Q%7BQ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B3%2C+0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+0%2C+5%2C+3%5D%0A%5B-34%2C+0%2C+1%2C+-34%2C+4%2C+8%2C+4%5D)

#### How it works

Pyth automatically stores the evaluated input in `Q` and prints all unused return values.

```
     {Q  Convert Q into a set. This removes duplicates.
  .-Q    Perform "bagwise" difference of Q and set(Q).
         This removes the first occurrence of all elements in Q.
 {       Convert to set to deduplicate.
S        Sort. Returns a list.
```

Answer (score 7):

## SQL, <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```sql
SELECT*FROM D GROUP BY I HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

I hope it is OK to assume the integers are stored in table D?
This will work in both SQLServer, PostgreSQL and possibly others.  Thanks to @manatwork from the 2 bytes.

Comment: Assuming i is the only field in table d, in PostgreSQL you can reduce it to `select*from d group by 1having count(*)>1`. (MySQL and SQLite's parser will also handle the unseparated `select*from` part, but they not understand `1having`.)

Comment: @manatwork cheers for that, sql server also understands the `select*from`.  Doesn't like the `1having` though.. will leave that as `I having`

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab / Octave, 40

I'm assuming input values are real (not complex). The input is in a variable `d`.

```
unique(d(sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq,d,d')))>1))
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/w5OldL) in Octave.

Comment: No need to input, you can assume data in variable 'd'

Comment: @garg10may Thanks. Updated. You should specify that in your post

Comment: The output is incorrect when `d = [3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 3]`. There are two `0`s.

Comment: @alephalpha Thanks! corrected (8 more bytes)

Comment: Shorter: `d(sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq,d,d')))==2)`. Or in Octave: `d(sum(triu(d==d'))==2)`

Comment: @alephalpha Good idea! You should post that as an answer yourself

Answer (score 6):

### Mathematica, <s>29</s> 26 bytes

Assuming that input is stored in `d`:

```
Select[d⋃d,d~Count~#>1&]
```

Otherwise, it's 29 bytes as an unnamed function:

```
Cases[#⋃#,n_/;#~Count~n>1]&
```

Here, `d⋃d` (or `#⋃#`) is a golfing trick to remove duplicates - by taking the set union with itself, Mathematica interprets the list as a set, removing duplicates automatically, while the actual union doesn't do anything.

Afterwards, both methods simply filter those elements which appear in the original list at least twice.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>13</s> 9 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
∊(⊂1↓⊣¨)⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1FHl8ajribDR22TH3UtPrRC81HPjv9pj9omPOqb6hXs7/eoY4bGo94@IM/T/1FX86H1xo/aJgJ5wUHOQDLEwzNYE6gEqvh/moJ6dKw6F4jSNdRRMNBRMIRyDRFMY7AESA6MgAxTHQVjmDZjE5gcmAlEFkAyVh0A)

`(`…`)⌸` for each unique element (left argument) and the indices where it occurs (right argument), apply the following tacit function:

`⊣¨` one of the left (the unique element) for each on the right (the indices)

`1↓` drop one

`⊂` enclose (prevents padding with zeros to create a non-ragged matrix)

`∊` **ϵ**nlist (flatten)

Answer (score 6):

## PowerShell, <s>31</s> 29 Bytes

```
($d|group|?{$_.Count-1}).Name
```

Assumes that `$d` is already populated (as given) -- e.g., `$d=@(-34,0,1,-34,4,8,4)`.

Pipes the array into the `Group-Object` cmdlet, which groups like-items together and spits out an object that's essentially an array of arrays. We pipe that to a `Where-Object` (the `?` operator) that has `Count` greater than one (i.e., there are duplicates), and output the `.Name` of those items. Has a side bonus of preserving the initial ordering, too.

<sub>Edit - saved two bytes thanks to [Danko Durbić](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/1308/danko-durbi%c4%87)</sub>

Comment: I think you can replace `$_.Count-gt1` with `$_.Count-1` which would be true for any `Count` greater than one.

Comment: @DankoDurbić Excellent!

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

Run this in the JavaScript console:

```js
e={};d.filter(x=>(e[x]=1+e[x]||0)==1)
```

Comment: It's generally accepted that JavaScript needs some sort of explicit "output/print" function (such as `console.log`, `alert`, etc) to be considered complete. If a challenge says "write a program or function", then function returns also suffice. Aside that, very efficient solution!

Comment: @Mwr247 The question states that the anwer may be a *snippet* which *evaluates to the correct result*.

Comment: It seems I misinterpreted that paragraph. Apologies then =)

Comment: @Mwr247 No problem! :)

Answer (score 6):

### Python 3.5, 30

```python
[x for x in{*d}if~-d.count(x)]
```

Uses Python 3.5's set unpacking. The `~-` subtracts 1, which takes a count of 1 to 0 which is Falsy.

This gives a list. If giving a set is OK, then we use a set comprehension, saving 1 char and not needing version 3.5:

```python
{x for x in d if~-d.count(x)}
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` for Python 3 is it valid only for 3.5? When has python started becoming esoteric.

Comment: @garg10may Just wait til you see [what 3.6 has in store...](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

Comment: @Sp3000 Awesome. Looks like the same set-up as Scala. Infinitely more readable than more alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

## R, <s>31</s> 24 bytes

Thanks to [flodel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/5163/flodel) for the 7 bytes.

Assuming the input is already in `d`.

#### code:

```
unique(d[duplicated(d)])
```

edit: now it outputs correctly if there are more than 2 duplicates as pointed by [aditsu](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/7416/aditsu).

Comment: That looks beautiful! But the 4th test case doesn't seem to be correct...

Comment: You can remove `which` since `[` also accepts a logical argument.

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
∪(d[find(sum(d.==d',1)-1)])
```

`d.==d'` creates a symmetric matrix with the value at `i,j` being true if `d[i]==d[j]` and false otherwise. `sum`ming in one dimension and then subtracting 1 will produce zero if there's only one of the element and nonzero if there's more than one. `find` will obtain the indexes of the non-zero elements, which are then used to index the array `d` itself. `∪` (union) acts like `unique` when used in this way, removing the repeats.

Old solution:

```
∪(filter(i->sum(d.==i)>1,d))
```

Simple - for each entry, it checks if there's more than one of it in the array. Those for which there are more than one are returned by "filter", and then `∪` (union) acts like `unique` when used in this way, removing the repeats.

Note: originally had it as a function, but question allows array to be stored in a variable, for which I've chosen `d` as suggested in the question.

Answer (score 5):

## Octave, 22 bytes

Based on [Luis Mendo's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60613/9288).

```
d(sum(triu(d==d'))==2)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>31</s> 29

```
Cases[{s_,t_/;t>1}:>s]@*Tally
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2.7, <s>36</s> 42

```
list(set(filter(lambda x:d.count(x)>1,d)))
```

*edit* : surrounded the expression with list(..) in order to comply with the  format required in the question

Comment: this will output set not a list

Comment: So shall I surround my snippet with a call to  list(...) ?

Comment: Yes the output should be an array only.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3 - <s>33</s> 30 bytes

`{_ for _ in d if d.count(_)>1}`

Repl output, `d` as input.

Answer (score 4):

## Shell + GNU coreutils, 12

```
sort|uniq -d
```

#### Test output:

```
$ printf "%s\n" -34 0 1 -34 4 8 4 | ./nonuniq.sh 
-34
4
$
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
ft/QT{Q
```

Explanation:

```
ft/QT{Q
           Q = eval(input())
     {Q    set(Q) - deduplicate
f          filter - with T as the filter variable.
  /QT      count in Q of T
 t         minus 1.
```

The filter removes all elements that appear exactly once from the set of elements.

Answer (score 4):

### LINQ,<strike>62</strike> 54 bytes

Kinda new here, but here goes nothing.

```
d.GroupBy(c=>c).Where(g=>g.Count()>1).Select(g=>g.Key)
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I don't know LINQ, but there's some whitespace you can probably remove from this to improve your score.

Answer (score 4):

## K (not K5), 10 bytes

```
x@&1<#:'=x
```

Assumes input is in `x`. I thought it'd be fun to do a non-K5 answer!

Comment: Assuming `k4`, `&` on a dictionary obviates the need for `x@`; it can also be made tacit as `&1<#:'=:` for 8 bytes (dropping the need for `x` to be initialized). As an aside, the order of the inputs is preserved either way.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 7 bytes

**Solution:**

```
&1<#:'=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X83QRtlK3dZYR8EAjAzBCMgw1VEw/v8fAA)

**Explanation:**

```
&1<#:'= / the solution
      = / group, key => value (index)
   #:'  / count length of each group
 1<     / 1 less than 
&       / keys where true
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), <s>[11](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/256322/1)</s> 10 bytes

```haskell
(!!1)~<<bg
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuxN1czcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXmm3M0tKSNF2LVRqKioaadTY2SekQgZs2uYmZebYp-VwKCgVFCioKaQrRRgpWVgqeeSU6CsY6CiY6CgY6CoY6CpY6CkZgESOwoBmQEQsxY8ECCA0A)

### Explanation

- `bg` sort a list into lists of like values.
- `(!!1)` get the second value or `[]` if there is none.

We use `~<<` to glue these together, which basically acts as a concat map.

### Reflection

This works pretty well, but the operator precedence is killing me.
Both of the following work but requires the parens to prevent an error.

```
nb<(df^*nb)
nb<(fdf~<nb)
```

If the operator precedence was different both of these would be competitive with the first one actually saving bytes.

I don't know if that means the precedence is wrong, but it's worth noticing.

`(!!)` should have a prefix function, *and* a bunch of versions with the index prefilled.  I noticed this earlier but still didn't fix it, and now it's coming back to haunt me.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>30</s> 28 bytes

In [the Interactive Ruby Shell](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html):

```rb
d.select{|x|d.count(x)>1}|[]
```

<sup>Saved 2 bytes thanks to [Kirill L.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78274/kirill-l)</sup>

Comment: Save 2 bytes: `d.select{|x|d.count(x>1)}|[]`

Comment: I think you mean `count(x)>1`, not `count(x>1)`.

Answer (score 3):

### Mathematica, 23 bytes

With input stored in `d`:

```
Pick[#,#2>1]&@@@Tally@d
```

As a function, 24 bytes:

```
Pick[#,#2>1]&@@@Tally@#&
```

for example, with

```
d = {3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 3}
Tally@d
```

returns this:

```
   {{3, 2},
    {0, 3},
    {1, 2},
    {5, 1}}
```

(first element of each sublist is the element, second one is frequency of occurrence). Applying to this list `Pick[#,#2>1]&@@@` transforms it to

```
{Pick[3,2>1], Pick[0,3>1], Pick[1,2>1], Pick[5,1>1]}
```

And where the second argument of `Pick` evaluates to `True` the first argument is returned.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl 6, 16 bytes

Assuming the list is stored in `$_` you could use any of the following snippets.
<sub><sup>( which was specifically allowed )</sup></sub>

```perl6
(--«.BagHash).Set.keys # 23 bytes
```

```perl6
keys .Bag (-) .Set # 18 bytes
```

```perl6
# U+2216 SET MINUS
keys .Bag∖.Set # 16 bytes in utf8
```

---

If you don't care that you get a Bag you could leave off `keys` .

```perl6
$_ = [3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 3];
.Bag∖.Set ∋ 3 # True
.Bag∖.Set ∋ 5 # False
```

---

None of these have the limitation of only working on signed integers, or even just numbers for that matter.

```perl6
say keys .Bag∖.Set given |(<a b c d a a c>), 1/3, 2/3 - 1/3;
# (a c 0.333333)
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>35</s> <s>28</s> 34 bytes

```
a=>a.filter(o=x=>(o[x]=-~o[x])==2)
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLy0zpyS1SCPftsLWTiM/uiLWVrcORGna2hpp/k/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTiI7V1FTQ11eIjuVCk9A11DHQMcQpbYiQM8SQNAZqBWrWARlhqmMMU2gMNhHDImMTsGIQbaJjoWMCUw4WwFBuoAOHMIUGsf8B)

Comment: Return `[0,0,0]` for `[0,0,0,0,0,0]`, intended?

Comment: @l4m2, fixed that.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
u-u¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6f@6ip8X@pbumhnf///4@OjtWJ1jXUMdAxBDIMwaQxkAfk64BETXWMQQqMTcAiINpEx0LHJDYWAA)

```
u       # unique element of
 -      # set difference between
  u¹    # unique elements of input  
        # and input
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$7 \log_{256}(96) \approx\$ 5.76 bytes

Note: this only works on Thunno 1.1.3+

```
gc1>kZU
```

(No ATO link since that's on v1.1.0 at the moment)

[image: Screenshot]

#### Explanation

```python
gc1>kZU   # Implicit input. The D flag duplicates it implicitly.
g   k     # Filter the input for elements where the following is truthy:
 c        #   The count of the element in the input
  1>      #   Is greater than 1
     ZU   # Deduplicate and output implicitly
```

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp, 57 bytes

```
(remove-duplicates(remove-if(lambda(x)(<(count x d)2))d))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Octave, 33 bytes

```
[~,a]=unique(d);d(a)=[];unique(d)
```

- Finds the indices of the first occurrence of each unique integer,
- removes those occurrences, and
- finds the unique elements of the remaining array.

Here it is on [ideone](http://ideone.com/MmIKGX). I've wrapped the snippet in a function so I could call it using all of the sample inputs.

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8, 80 Bytes**

```
x.stream().filter(i->x.indexOf(i)!=x.lastIndexOf(i)).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Assuming x contains the input List of numbers.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 35 <s>37</s> bytes

Pretty straight forward:

```
array_diff_key($a,array_unique($a))
```

---

**As a note:** I didn't add the `;` at the end of the line, as the questions states:

> Your answer may be a snippet which assumes the input to be stored in a variable (d, say) and evaluates to the correct result

So this snippet could be used like this and evaluates to the correct result:

```
print implode(' ', array_diff_key($a,array_unique($a)));
```

---

**Another note**

The code above works for all test cases provided in the challenge. In those all non-unique characters are at most duplicates. If a element can occur more than two times, another `array_unique()` would be necessary, which increases the length to **49 bytes**:

```
array_unique(array_diff_key($a,array_unique($a)))
```

---

**Edits**

- *Saved* **2 bytes** by replacing `array_diff_assoc` with `array_diff_key`. Thanks to [Jörg Hülsermann](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59107/j%C3%B6rg-h%C3%BClsermann).

Comment: `array_diff_key` instead `array_diff_assoc`

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Good catch. Thanks. Will take a look at your other suggestions within the next days.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```
â £kX â
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AihUOLsyMUDi/6/z9a19hER8FAR8FQRwHMBCILIBnLxaWbAQA)

### Explanation:

```
â £kX â
â         // Get all unique items from the input
  £       // Map X through the results
   kX     //   Remove X from the input
      â   //   Get unique items
-h        // Return the last item
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 10 bytes

```
duplicates
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQUJRaUlJZUJSZV6JQnFpSrGDNxVWtoGtsomCgYAimTRQsgLiW639KaUFOZnJiSWrxf73/AA)

Builtin

Answer (score 2):

## Elm, 91 bytes

```
e=List.member
g x z=case z of
 a::b->g(a::x)b++if e a b&&not(e a x)then[a]else[]
 _->[]
```

```
g[]
```

Comment: Your `e` function is the same as `List.member` (though you'll still want to alias it).

Answer (score 2):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/index.html), 58 bytes

```
x!(y:z)|elem y z&&all(/=y)x=y:(y:x)!z|1>0=x!z
_![]=[]
```

```
([]!)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m706ubSoqDK-IDE7uXjBgqWlJWm6FjdNKxQ1Kq2qNGtSc1JzFSoVqtTUEnNyNPRtKzUrbCutgHIVmopVNYZ2BrYVilVc8YrRsbbRsRDNO3MTM_MUbBWiYxUUFaINdYx1jIDQRMcYKg-zBAA)

Weirdish port of [my Elm answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256440/56656).  Curry has nicer built in functions and pattern matching than Elm.

Answer (score 1):

## [Hassium](http://HassiumLang.com), 104 Bytes

```
func main(){r=[];i=[];foreach(e in d)if(!i.contains(e))i.add(e)else if(!r.contains(e))r.add(e);print(r)}
```

Run online and see expanded [here](http://HassiumLang.com/Hassium/index.php?code=119ec21172011f2652db5c61fc715764)

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 143 bytes

There are already some very good Python answers out there (see @dieters, @ppperry & @xnor answers) so I decided to take a different approach, have some fun with recursion and python `lambda` functions and see what could I come up with. This is not even close to the best answers here but it was fun to think.

The program takes the integer list as a parameter of function `p` and returns a list containing non-unique elements.

```
p=lambda i:[j for j in(lambda n:[]if len(n)<=1 else[(lambda x:x[0]if len([1 for o in x[1:]if x[0]==o])==1 else 'N')(n)]+p(n[1:]))(i) if j!='N']
```

Two line version for better readability:

```
p=lambda i:[j for j in(lambda n:[]if len(n)<=1 else[(lambda x:x[0]if 
len([1 for o in x[1:]if x[0]==o])==1 else 'N')(n)]+p(n[1:]))(i) if j!='N']
```

#### Short Explanation

The inner `lambda` takes a list `x` as a parameter and returns the first element of such list if it is repeated only once in the rest of the list (`x[1:]`). If not it returns `'N'`.

The `lambda` in between the outer and inner `lambdas` is the one in charge of the recursive search. This returns a list containing the non-unique elements and plenty of `'N's`. This is the one which takes the integer list as a parameter.

The outer `lambda` filters the resulting list getting rid of the unwanted `'N's`.

#### Test cases

```
p([])
[]
p([-1,0,1])
[]
p([3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 5, 3])
[3,0,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

### STATA, 18 bytes

```
bys v:drop if _n-2
```

Note that this requires the paid version of STATA.

Assumes the data is stored in a variable `v` and then the result will be in `v` at the end. It works by sorting by `v` and grouping duplicate values together. Each duplicate value will have at least two values, which means it can drop anything that is not the second element of each value. Third and subsequent elements will already be represented and the first element will either be unique or represented by the second.

For example, make a file a.b with data:

```
3
0
0
1
1
0
5
3
```

Then run the following code

```
insheet using a.b,clear
rename v1 v
bys v:drop if _n-2 //the actual code that does stuff
list v,noobs noheader
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>12</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
~.d#~1<+/=/~d
```

Assumes the list is in `d`.

Explanation:

```
         =/~d   NB. compare each element in d to each element in d
       +/       NB. sum the columns (giving amount of occurrences)
     1<         NB. see which columns are greater than 1 (=not unique)
  d#~           NB. select those elements from d 
~.              NB. unique elements from that
```

If an anonymous function is OK as well, it can be shortened to <s>13</s> 12:

```
~.#~1<+/"1@=
```

Answer (score 1):

**C# - 40**

```
i.GroupBy(g=>g).SelectMany(s=>s.Skip(1))
```

Using select many to be able to use Skip and skip the first occurrence if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes, language postdates challenge

```
œ-QQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@390sm5g4P///6ONdRQMwMgQjIAMUx0F41gA)

Same algorithm as the accepted answer, just a shorter syntax.

Comment: This look so cryptic 0.o what is that first character?

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 75 bytes

```php
function a($b){return array_unique(array_diff_assoc($b,array_unique($b)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MUEjVUkjSri1JLSouAnKKixMr40rzMwtJUDQgnJTMtLT6xuDg/GahQB0UBUKOmpnXt/7LEoviU0twCjUSNaPVEdR0FEyMdBfUkGCNRPVZTk4vL3u4/AA)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7, 36 bytes

```
list({x for x in i if i.count(x)>1})
```

Where `i` is the input

Comment: You'll need to make it a lambda function because snippets aren't allowed.

Comment: 3 other people did the same thing, and OP doesn't seem to mind

Comment: "Your answer may be a snippet which assumes the input to be stored in a variable". Note that this is not the default, but this question is old and the OP explicitly allowed it, so it is okay.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> <s>6</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
¢ÏKÙ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0KLD/d6HZ/7/H22oY6RjDMSGQGimY6JjqmMWCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeXhCS7/Dy063O99eOZ/nf/R0bE6CtG6hjoGOoYgliGEMgbygSI6IHFTHWOwGmMTsBCINtGx0DGBKDfSMQZikEozoLCpjllsLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
      #  e.g. input=[1,2,3,2,1,1,6,4,5,6]
¢     # Count how many times each item of the (implicit) input-list occurs in the
      # (implicit) input-list
      #  → [3,2,1,2,3,3,2,1,1,2]
 Ï    # Only keep the values in the (implicit) input-list at the truthy (==1) indices
      #  → [3,4,5]
  K   # Remove those values from the (implicit) input-list, leaving all non-unique items
      #  → [1,2,2,1,1,6,6]
   Ù  # Uniquify that list of non-unique items
      #  → [1,2,6]
      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 41 bytes

```
{it.filter{v->it.count{it==v}>1}.toSet()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU/BioMwEL37FUNPyUGp6MJSqrDHhd78gYZuLGHjKMkoFMm324l2wcI@SGbmzePNzG9P1uAyKQs4nkBcjKfzN1ItIa2h0VsB1TIbylpjSbt5Smsubv2IxGxVTaHOQ0Y9q4UMSzsidMqgUO7uT/DlnHqcG3IG7@w6J8CI8yyP8lBB8/Cku@xq8Lr2IjKn1Y92Qr4zF4Pa78lODS/HP/BmfrCGxAEO8p/@S0M937VzigjJe7Z@be9E3BQMbhvLneHAR5FFgeOqkZtfSMKS5nCEPMn5FZxxDpH5gCJJi3KtYyzhE8on)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 14 bytes

```perl6
*.repeated.Set
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0uvKLUgNbEkNUUvOLXkvzVXcWKlQppGdKwmnKlrqKNgoKNgiCRkiMo1BisAqQEjIMNUR8EY2QhjE5g8mAlEFkASqOI/AA)

Gets a `Set` of the `repeated` elements.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 60 bytes

```javascript
f=>[...new Set(f.filter(e=>f.indexOf(e)!=f.lastIndexOf(e)))]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9mC0R20Xp6enmp5QrBqSUaaXppmTklqUUaqbZ2aXqZeSmpFf5pGqmairZpejmJxSWecBFNzdj/yfl5xfk5qXo5@ekaaRrRxjoKBmBkCEZAhqmOgnGspqY1F5pKXWMTmEIwE4gsgCRWpRCTDEFy/wE)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes (another try)

```javascript
a=>a.filter((t={},e=>!(1-(t[e]=++t[e]|0))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9oC0R2iXppmTklqUUaGiW21bU6qbZ2ihqGuhol0amxttraIKrGQBMI/ifn5xXn56Tq5eSna3ApAEGiRrSxjoIBGBmCEZBhqqNgHKvJpWnNhU29rrEJTLmFjoIJSCGqOk5MRToKQAGQyv8A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 9 bytes

```
peJNB\\NB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/Z@Tl1v9vyDVy88pJsbP6X/t/@parmpdQwUDBUMgwxBMGgN5QL4CSNRUwRikwNgELAKiTRQsFExqAQ)

```
pe # Parse and push
J  # Duplicate
NB # Remove duplicate elements
\\ # Difference between nubbed and original lists
NB # Nub the difference
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 18 bytes

Since a snippet is allowed here, the input is assumed to be in `@F`.  The TIO link adds a little I/O around it.

```perl
grep++$k{$_}==2,@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9X5xYqZCWX/Q/vSi1QFtbJbtaJb7W1tZIx8Ht/39DBSMFYwUTBVMgaamgC@T@yy8oyczPK/6v62uqZ2Bo8F83EQA)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 24 bytes

```r
names((t=table(v))[t>1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc29CsIwEAfwvU9x4HIHERJDB4X6IuJwba9SaJOQHAWfPsbBRX7r/yPXY5jQG9u4xpreeKqBdymIOiiPm@BB9NC7e1I9QczABRiKcpjPvMUgkHJ8Zd5hDUWFZ4jLNxDWlEQBl1a5XGF8qxS6dX/bZeKA9DvoPNjGNRZ68PUD)

Completely different approach to the [previous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/60640/95126) [R](https://www.r-project.org/) answer for the same number of bytes when written (as here) as a snippet with pre-defined variable `v`, but 4 bytes shorter as a full program (which, admittedly, isn't required by the challenge).
Outputs the non-unique elements as a vector of strings.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 25 bytes

```r
(r=rle(sort(v)))$v[r$l>1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1LCsMgEAbgfU4x0CxGsKCVLFpIL1K6mCamBKzKjAg9vbW78G3/B7c6L@i06Wxn9KSdasgzB4@SuGBVSo31wWO422c7QWIgAQIpFNczhRQ9ZE5vpg/sUYqnFdL2D8Q9Z18At165XOH1LV7UbTiOy0IR1fFhcGA62xmYwLUf)

One byte longer (and yet another approach) if you want to output as an integer vector.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
UÞ⊍U
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiVcOe4oqNVSIsIiIsIlstMzQsIDAsIDEsIC0zNCwgNCwgOCwgNF0iXQ==)

Multiset Symmetric difference is very powerful

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 36 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.filter(o=x=>a.a+a+a==(o[x]+=a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLy0zpyS1SCPftgLES9QGQltbjfzoilht20RNzf/J@XnF@Tmpejn56RppGtGxmpoK@voK0bFcaBK6hjoGOoY4pQ0RcoYYksZArUDNOiAjTHWMYQqNwSZiWGRsAlYMok10LHRMYMrBArH/AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 22 bytes

```
[group_by(.)[][1:2][]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z86vSi/tCA@qVJDTzM6NtrQyig2OjYWKB6rgB1wResa6igY6CgYxmLIGGIRhcgYg7WAdIERkGGqo2AcCzLN2AQmAWYCkQWQjP2XX1CSmZ9X/F83GQA)

Explanation:

```sh
[                    ]     # collect
                   []      # each
              [1:2]        # second item
            []             # from each
 group_by( )               # array of arrays of
          .                # identical values
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) coreutils, 15 bytes

```sh
sort|uniq -d|rs
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVnNVVSsYKBgqGBjY6Ok4qBUE/O/OL@opKY0L7NQQTelpqj4P1ctV5qCrrEJWBmINlGwUDABihkDRUBihkDSVMEYKAJkg9SCBECM/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-p`, 11 bytes

```
UQ:_Ng>1FIg
```

Takes the integers as command-line arguments. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboFS7IKlpSVpuharQwOt4v3S7QzdPNMhIlCJndG6xiY6CgY6CoY6CmAmEFkASZhOAA)

#### Explanation

```
UQ:_Ng>1FIg
          g  List of command-line arguments
        FI   Filter by this function:
   _N          The number of times this element appears in
     g         the list of command-line arguments
      >1       is greater than one
UQ:          Uniquify the resulting list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 40 bytes

```arturo
unique select b'x[1<size select b=>[=x]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?zaZV8D)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ü lÉ cÎ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=/CBsySBjzg&input=WwpbXQpbLTEsMCwxXQpbMSwxXQpbMywwLDAsMSwxLDAsNSwzXQpbLTM0LDAsMSwtMzQsNCw4LDRdClswLDAsMCwwLDAsMF0KXS1tUg) (includes all test cases)

```
ü lÉ cÎ     :Implicit input of integer
ü           :Group & sort by value
  l         :Filter by length
   É        :  Minus 1
     c      :Flat map
      Î     :  First element
```