# Count repetitions of an array

Tags: code-golf, array

You will receive an array and must return the number of integers that occur more than once.

```
[234, 2, 12, 234, 5, 10, 1000, 2, 99, 234]
```

This will return 2, since each of `234` and `2` appear more than once.

```
[234, 2, 12, 234]
[2, 12, 234, 5, 10, 1000, 2]
```

The list will never be more than 100k integers long, and the integers inside the list will always be in between -100k and 100k.

Integers should be counted if they occur more than once, so if an integer occurs 3 times then it will still only count as one repeated integer.

**Test cases**

```
[1, 10, 16, 4, 8, 10, 9, 19, 2, 15, 18, 19, 10, 9, 17, 15, 19, 5, 13, 20]  = 4
[11, 8, 6, 15, 9, 19, 2, 2, 4, 19, 14, 19, 13, 12, 16, 13, 0, 5, 0, 8]     = 5
[9, 7, 8, 16, 3, 9, 20, 19, 15, 6, 8, 4, 18, 14, 19, 12, 12, 16, 11, 19]   = 5
[10, 17, 17, 7, 2, 18, 7, 13, 3, 10, 1, 5, 15, 4, 6, 0, 19, 4, 17, 0]      = 5
[12, 7, 17, 13, 5, 3, 4, 15, 20, 15, 5, 18, 18, 18, 4, 8, 15, 13, 11, 13]  = 5
[0, 3, 6, 1, 5, 2, 16, 1, 6, 3, 12, 1, 16, 5, 4, 5, 6, 17, 4, 8]           = 6
[11, 19, 2, 3, 11, 15, 19, 8, 2, 12, 12, 20, 13, 18, 1, 11, 19, 7, 11, 2]  = 4
[6, 4, 11, 14, 17, 3, 17, 11, 2, 16, 14, 1, 2, 1, 15, 15, 12, 10, 11, 13]  = 6
[0, 19, 2, 0, 10, 10, 16, 9, 19, 9, 15, 0, 10, 18, 0, 17, 18, 18, 0, 9]    = 5
[1, 19, 17, 17, 0, 2, 14, 10, 10, 12, 5, 14, 16, 7, 15, 15, 18, 11, 17, 7] = 5
```

Comment: What do you mean by `Once it counts the repetition, don't count again`? Also, since we want to find the repetition of a specific integer, how would we know which integer to search for if we are not given it? Lastly, the test cases are a bit confusing; which are output and which are input?

Comment: I've edited this to try to make it a bit clearer. Is this what you intended? Also, please put answers in for those test cases.

Comment: You may want to add some edge cases, like lists with negative, large-magnitude, unique, or no integers.

Comment: I have added some answers to the test cases, sorry if I go them wrong

Comment: I've voted to close this question until you confirm this is what you intended.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/60610/non-unique-elements) (output the non-unique items, instead of the amount of non-unique items).

Answer (score 16):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 20 bytes

Is this what you are after?  Uses `table` to count the occurrences of each of the `scan` input values.  Tests if count is > 1 and sums the trues.

```r
sum(table(scan())>1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0V6MkMSknVaM4OTFPQ1PTzlDzv6GCoYGCoZmCiYIFiGWpYGipYKRgaKpgaAFiQoTMwQKWCkDCWMHI4D8A)

Comment: my mind went to `duplicated` first -- the humble `table` is so useful for golfing!

Comment: @giuseppe table is a favorite now :)

Answer (score 9):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 18

```bash
sort|uniq -d|wc -l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi/qKSmNC@zUEE3paY8WUE35/9/I2MTLiMuQyMuEMOUy9AAiAwMgEKWliAhAA)

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

```hs
f s=sum[1|x<-[-9^6..9^6],filter(==x)s>[x]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZLBboMwDIbvPEUOO2wSVCGEEKSxF0GZ1EPR0GhVlU5C2vbszPHvDHbfwcQk8effdt6O8/tpmtZ1UHM3f5z78mt5LvqifXWHA31CPozT/XR77LrlaX7plxDW83G8qE5db@Plrh7UoPoyV6Umc7myufL4a2khM7TUZB6/6aSRbfLjUtFFHbLss8j@jaZIpCVcyRCHKxvHMJ4paaW40iBz9DXT6OuJpSKuznq610AV3aoYaLTE15zGA@x3YLMDx/LakHBcaQNrUJ9nLwqopBOoqmauY0WRahGlIU5wBsECqJlhEcwya7D8ZtJj6RvLq4LgNMe7JCGVwFupWdiDODQgZre/XUvqHEYh3U@pZGoecDFWWonE1DIURq5Jk8UD4VPpRSWll5tWywgRKm3kPPpPsY6LFXFajuUVypuRCacDD7fZOhkfY9hGIbOXcWiIsDu0wSwssjQ7fV60xUcRGFd8rz8) Abuses the fact the the integers in the list are guaranteed to be within -100k and 100k.

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-1 thanks to ngn

Anonymous tacit prefix function.

```apl
+/1<⊢∘≢⌸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZI9TgMxEIX7nGJ7FuG/XTsSHQ2pkAgXiIRCEwna1EgRRBBBgUSdC9BScxRfZBm/N2aXwuuf2ffNm7FXD5vT2@1qc383DCdn9jzvj/npMz8f88v3sM67t/x6yIePxVXeP/58@bx7l93y@kK@N5eL5bBubNtYI6Nvm9A2ibu5TDKcTJ2MxG2NRD2WdZm8/GhmQrLQ94yOCAcyAHUWiXVMWtYGIPkmwUg80ohEPUDOqK4DPhGYJkA3AZaK5sWPUa8RREdJZEqvZbOEDsQeHgovUIWqHDWq6yAN1MBXR0Qah/ZRewM/XkgG0r4mrXZxVBvCM9phsSVxYGdYGZSVq9eQiNMBW179tH@yyKUTEi8bAS3Va4l2NBagVlfaJaQw/4tSS0Yj@pj0/vXWaiBxGcdmlTc14zOcj/dlmDhMmI59DsTHiaekfso9/wI)

`+/` sum of

`1<` whether 1 is less than

…`⌸` for each unique element:

`⊢∘` ignoring the actual unique element,

`≢` the count of its occurrences

Comment: `{1<≢⍵}⌸` -> `1<⊢∘≢⌸`

Comment: @ngn Thanks. Incorporated.

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 40 bytes

```cs
n=>n.GroupBy(c=>c).Count(c=>c.Count()>1)
```

The first draft of the spec was unclear, and I thought it mean return all the elements that appear more than once. This is the updated version.

Somehow I didn't notice that my code returned the number of elements that appeared once. Thanks to Paul Karam for catching that!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY49C8IwFEV3f0XIYgIx1KqD9mNQVAqCooODOMT4CoEaS5oIIv722oYO6nAv53J48GQ1kJWqV07LOFtqdwMjLgXEStuUtZUntU5Szdfm7sr5k8gklZQv7k5bzx3SdEjrqPcQBolkD@K6URoI5XsoCyGBYIQZxl/79LfPfke9o1EW/DHOdOksmqFX8MZM/Lqts43sXE4EP5SFsqTP@pQfoABpSfM93wlTAaU0qk/haMxQyNCwiedJw0GbIPBiOvXi/AE)

Comment: Your output is wrong, it needs to count the elements with 2 or more occurences. It should be `n=>n.GroupBy(c=>c).Count(c=>c.Count()>=2)`. The OP says the answer of this list is 2. Your code returns 5. The change I gave you returns 2.

Comment: Or just `>1` to keep the 40 bytes count

Comment: @PaulKaram I didn't notice that, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## [C (clang)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) <s>175</s> <s>117</s> 95 bytes

```c
c(*a,*b){return*a-*b;}r(*l,m){qsort(l,m,4,c);return((!m||l[1]-*l)&l[-1]==*l)+(m?r(l+1,m-1):0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZRhb5swEIa/51d4rTbZFBTbGDBD0X5Ilg80IRMSkJWm07Q0vz0zd2egaiQiOT7My3Ov7wz7aN@U3a/bbc@DMgyexaWvzm99F5RR8Fxcex40YSsuL6@n/sxdGJpwLwrUcP6lfX9vtmoXBY341mwjtdtsXPjE2x89b55U2EZKfJeiuN4eD9Wx7irWvbVVw/8Kxl/rf9Xp6MK1j7ZyJ8Sq7s6sVNsd27CLCpmSbqQhMyGzeJW7yQ3tpsQNi5f@TkbLLh6m2AnltWCI1YRVAEtROvE0pAGan93zSqODIZZAdf/WMd0PsTFinT5Dl04dA1hL4iSQzmICO0ugZwmG7eYDGLGG3EraVgZ8jYAMDcVUIdxtAvwUHA50g09JNEvYhLAaIQRKgGUQArYTZNppUA@ormA3HmubIlYCJ/WW/NZgyRcT19AsFmZwYcaqspnbbGoZdcmnpi5bTEIDnMdk2ZcUN@pCPbq1iMWDBSqqVUwlUZN3AygyTmWGfPJTEfKxCGRWkoxOMZ01OhH@hsUwmyo9HGaoBb0Ocnof8uk0SHRlZjk0Ns1gumxm2JLZ4RRdixWA27Lu@J9TfRDssmLsd@8Wj/zh6@Fn9xD2vFQhvq@lEkJAa9Zr58Pc02qv1R@0yT1t7LXxstZ4rVnWJl6bLGtTr00/aNN72sxrs@U6WK@1y9zca/Nlv669vhkS1aMWv8dMFqvr7T8)

This is the first time I've submitted one of these, so let me know if there are any issues with formatting or anything.

Updates from the comments:

- -58 to 117 bytes from Jo King
- -80 to 95 bytes from ASCII-only

[original submission](https://tio.run/##hZTRjpswEEXf8xXuVl3hhCjGGDCifEnKAxuSCikhLZutVs3y7el4ZhxYNRKRHBv7@sz1jGG33h3r7uft1nYXsQv@nNtmKerwRV77/eWt78QygJWlrNc8eCkGJ@3dkzhuq/Akr27YlKr4/XruL8ExPIWv7d/9@RAct6qS4U4WhzNtaMuoaL@XpzV0qxXsPAQgaldR9aWEvvr4aEu3Kp@f4XEdVSVOy2uzWhXDwJ6aYrh9bfaHttuL7u20PwbvUgQc811u/MhFlwsXt462lSjFNQpFpKCloTChsPSUQwdNQ5dAs/ToVzKehrHrYhCqoRCE1YyNEJaSdORpDIM038P@SJMDN1ZIhX8LTPgRNiYs6DNyCeoYwVoxJ8FwlgLYSQA9CeCOmzswYQ27VXysDPmaABkZijlDdNoE@Sk6dHRDuxSZZWzCWE0QBiXIMgRB2wkx7di4BpxXtBvfc5sSViEn9Zb80XDKJ5PmyCwlxrkw96yKidtsLBlXyYfmKlsKwg2dx2zZp5QOCkN9d2sJSxcLVZyrmFMSjd4Notg4pxnjqf@SkN@TwGYVy/gW813jG@EXLA2zMdPuMmMu@HVQ4/uQj7dBkSsziaGpaIbCZRPDls26WzQUCwSf6rbDj4gU14UQv3qYPARP35of3VPYB3UU0vtaR1JKLM1mAz7MI632Wv1JmzzSxl4bz2uN15p5beK1ybw29dr0kzZ9pM28NpvPg/VaO8/NvTaf9wvl9cVQpL5r@TurisVw@wc)

Comment: You need to include any includes your function uses as part of the submission. That said, it compiles perfectly fine without the includes

Comment: [122](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49190573#49190573)

Comment: Welcome, nice start.  I'm not a C person but here's a link to a [tips for golfing C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2203/31347) page

Comment: 117 bytes => `d,i;c(*a,*b){return*a-*b;}r(l[],m){qsort(l,m,4,c);for(i=d=0;++i<m;)d+=((l[i+1]-l[i]||i>m-2)&&l[i-1]==l[i]);return d;}`. As @ASCII-only noted, the `include`s don't affect the compilation of your program

Comment: @JoKing Nice! I just learned about some of these tricks to shorten it from the link MickyT posted. Also, does that mean the include *does not* need to be included in the submission?

Comment: @JoKing 100: `d;c(*a,*b){return*a-*b;}r(*l,m){qsort(l,m,4,c);for(d=0;~m--;)d+=(!m||l[1]-*l)&l[-1]==*l++;return d;}`

Comment: @CollinPhillips yes. as you can see in the link i posted, it still compiles fine without the includes

Comment: 95: `c(*a,*b){return*a-*b;}r(*l,m){qsort(l,m,4,c);return((!m||l[1]-*l)&l[-1]==*l)+(m?r(l+1,m-1):0);}`

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>11</s> 9 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to Jonah!

```
1#.1<1#.=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVHLToVADF3LV5zo4sbEkOkMMMONfI2RGDcu7tpvx55TwGskZCidnkfbz229LT0SrkibPfX26seyPXePPS7r0l/wgu8r1lvXvb99fOEhPisMlmATBjRGM2xGho2wxjBSVYkZfhTkhBNsjpp4ueOy8xAVZ4FlcnuQHJu82J8DPKNSc0Lx0EmJGJ2tkaMdHPngMP7@Kie5qs6RWV0pUpSmy9E5JohzYFXCvbIzCuuQ0UED62lgRLStVwNRw5QuJzg5YpJK@AIboEf@UZc9OPkQ3eKvssWcglQzbch7l7RQpL7XVX7zCeaSeKGOihqw3YSnIAvqnXTpn20JJ91o41qZZh6Zhphpi3C@t61V1JhkllxgMic2kK0e2k3CvpjtBw)

### Original solution:

```
1#.(1<#)/.~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVLLTsNADLz3K0b0UCqh4N1NsrsV/RpEhLhw6Bl@PXjGTSkiihLH63nYzse6XM4DDCfYmvbDY3rZH5@H7/W4exhwWM7DAU/4OmG57HZvr@@fWJDLiIyUFUxI5reZp3pnaitLOpkxojHqSJ0wBzSGkapKdNIUZMMNnBw18/CKy85DVDwL5Z3bA3OsebFfG7ijUnNG8dBJiZicrZGjbRx540j8/FU2uarOkVldKVKUpsvJOWaIc2SV4V7ZGYV1yOSgkfU0MCHa1q2BqGFKlxvYHDFLJXyBDdAjv6jLHpx8jG7xVznFnIJUM22xJS7KpNZIpbrKd76BuSQeqKOiBtLVhKcgC@qddPbPtoQtfgSCtDLNPDINMdMWYb@3rVXUmGSWXGAyJzaSrW7aTcK@mPUH)

Explanation:

```
        /.~   group the list by itself
   (   )      for each group
    1<#       is the length greater than 1
1#.           sum by base-1 conversion
```

Comment: Hey Galen.  `1#.1<1#.=` for 9 bytes + good ol' self-classify fun.

Comment: @Jonah Thanks! Honestly, I wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @Jonah [Nice!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/180346/43319)

Comment: @Adám and here i was pleased that i'd gotten J to tie with APL.  Foiled again :)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
Ù¢≠O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8MxDix51LvD//z/aUEfB0ACIzXQUTHQULCA8SyAFxEZAyhSILSBcmIw5VBjIBlHGQIUGsQA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##VVK5ccNAEMtdBQtgcC9vlXucOnGmUSDNKHDkwFW4BGUal2J34kboPQA3pILlPUtggd37@Dxf3q/r28vz@nv7@f77ur@u83qM8xSDxzJPZZ6Mp4MvHsmX6mE8jkzTte/7kv3HcHo6xgj8wuxGkcAMgrE6JCYW7fsAIv@a03i@UYhnM4hSEK6C3khoO8K0I@yODl1PkNYGxkRIY8ks27RQwbhAQ@crRMFVIka4CmghBroqKWwL9VG9gZ7sTAHQZRQdcnE1GsI7yqHZXriwM3QG5ODVGIx0CsjK0jMaQhe@Tc7EYSMhq1kW4yasAC1V6hJKhEdTkhSU0WPS/DW1kTBu29as/qa6Nw1SrQ4sXHaciX0upG87TSY9fc6nfw)

**Explanation**

```
   O  # sum
  ≠   # the false values
 ¢    # in the count
Ù     # of each unique digit in input
```

Comment: So all values that are not 1 are false?

Comment: @Adám: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda a:sum(a.count(x)>1for x in{*a})
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZNRS8MwFIXf/RUBX1opkiZpkwrzj2geqlIcbO2YG0zE316Te27aTgsOsmVJ852Tc28Pn6f3oddjt3ked@3@5a0V7cPHeZ@196/DuT9ll/yx7IajuIht/3XXfufj4bgN6132pLQphCpEGQbNqzCXcUhJG01DG17898nz241QNxO5ZFBdiIB1@BdgZQPBKOTwN@1YXm5gQ4cHpWeyWZBL4tV4ekYqUiJg@tW4WTQR55LA4dv52XM1k8MRC6/hgCa2koyqSNFBwy001EIjXrrxK2SKwmJYBOBoFm1pjgrXrkiiJp9RwOCU9GLVc9RmcGRVhDPgkPkKWDcPrgdnTKa1/0uWhKqTsXRHWkrBYg2WkVA0YqaEF57r6wpy0ZIBrrubupE6UrJFByk@ZjFVK72BbqMHOTfN2ZTzDQzR2D5HTpLydxr1VRpsWaZXBDhuQO6RtOEwtXPqscn9agW5kbiKeO/IZIIplNBA0C5cO3Yc28ozefwB)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ĠITL
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///IAs8Qn////0cbGZvoKBjpKBgCMZhtCmQbgLCBAVjC0hIsEQsA)**

...Or  `ĠIƇL`

#### How?

```
ĠITL - Link: list of integers   e.g. [234, 2, 12, 234, 5, 10, 1000, 2, 99, 234]
Ġ    - group indices by value        [[2,8],5,6,3,9,[1,4,10],7]
 I   - incremental differences       [[6],[],[],[],[],[3,6],[]]
  T  - truthy indices                [1,6]
   L - length                        2
```

`IƇ` would filter to keep only truthy results of `I` (`[[6],[3,6]]`) which also has the desired length.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>74</s> 73 bytes

```java
L->L.stream().filter(i->L.indexOf(i)<L.lastIndexOf(i)).distinct().count()
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##dZRNT@MwEIbv/AofE6lYzlfjCHalPSJl4cBxtQeTpsgldVHisosQv72MZyZNWiBSEseeeead8Tgb82IuN6unQ9OZYRC/jXVvF0JY59t@bZpW3IZPIe4eNm3jRRNtwEHuve3kr743r7UdvKjjKzB6v4DH4I23jbgVTvwQh/ryZy0H37dmG8VybTugRjZMWrdq/9@tIxtf1xJC@5vjRCxXALWu8eDT7PYO3oerAH/eP3QA5xgvO7sSWxAc3fveusc/f4WJSa1vBx@lWb4Q6UIkcOO4gLEKt1K4UFW4gOLZJ2GT5UKAg6YvMEsqQgWEps9xpeTpigJkYKhOkAmClmQ2sVIMgaTxnZHYED2MFRLhqec8MCxJGphlSEwVAwqMo4msZ@R0Rg45VicKFadRIjol35JEZFwRyq5A9BJVBXBOXqcJp@TMgAIZOTmj0oJYerq51lw/VJjNkQoZy1HGmAlOjUWjORJIdQgK8rPqUfaIGCPx5uljs2DDKNaiCc1uJQ3TOZJ6BS24HBlnn0xSc8SwTq4kxlLf5Msi1dizxOH24b0eFzQNy6mgoTfP@7qadpn6H0WNjJQ2Jac45UylZoWhOz4ddDyEGOIGfhmPbS@lPB7D@9fBt1u523v5DCfUdy5ysolc@0988Rs5/7UM0gw4b2K4KPD74QM)

**Explanation:**

```java
L->                      // Method with ArrayList parameter and integer return-type
  L.stream()             //  Create a stream of the input-list
   .filter(i->           //  Filter it by:
     L.indexOf(i)        //   Where the first index of a value
     <L.lastIndexOf(i))  //   is smaller than the last index of a value
   .distinct()           //  Deduplicate this filtered list
   .count()              //  And return the count of the remaining values
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 7 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
/+>1⍘⊚⊛
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgLys-MeKNmOKKmuKKmwoKZiBbwq8xIMKvMSDCrzIgwq8yIDAgMCAxIDEgMiAyIDMgNCA1IDYgN10KZiBbMSAyIDMgOTkgNCA1IDk5IDZdCmYgWzEgMiAzXQpmIFtd)

```
/+>1⍘⊚⊛
      ⊛  # classify (i.e. map integers -> naturals)
    ⍘⊚   # inverse where (occurrences)
  >1     # where are they greater than one?
/+       # sum
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.uniq.count{|x|a.count(x)>1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZPLboMwEEX3fIWlblqJImMbbBbJjyAvaNSo3aQPgZQK@HZqzx1j1E0jORmwfe6dR76nl5/tetqez8M8VNPt/au6fEy3cV7uy4Dw8f50rtd164teaVMKVYo6LIqbEMu4pKSNrqMNL/77lA8noYq@5vttKQLN4Skw6g46ke/wmHYsv@6grsNB6QE0AVgTpsWhTFIkQJz0q5FH1I6xJF74dn532BR9OGnhLJzThFSSCQ0JOaDdAa0O6Jhi5zOQ8rVYFlk6iqIJzfVAbg2RW3IVuQa3pBdHh1GJeRHREMXgOlltQHN5ca25fmRR@x0oidAmGykRepWKhncwiDJEfbNXLzts0RTuQ5LjDrp9nGikJBtyUOBrFqHKXca40D7XRHMB6uzXEITNcjlJSf5JuaWU2aBMEw0KTxB3O204hDZXNA6nPzaFJ4Ebg38HWUoMha4Y6NiDR8f@4oB4Bvrqdbi8zcu4fIprP/p1@wU)

Comment: Ruby 2.7, 24 bytes: [`->a{a.tally.count{_2>1}}`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=hZNLTsMwEIYX7HoKS2zTyq_EzqK9SGShUFGxqAChZFGlvQIXYFMhuANn4TTY84_jiA2V3Ew89jf_PPL--Tren64fh-3XOBzW_nu966d-M_TH42mzfx6fhulO79TlAvfPzVu36rSxldCVUHGRXUdbpiUlOdqWHEH896tut0KvOsX3m0pEmsdbZKgWcRLf4zV7HG-3iG7iQRkAtBGoCNPgUCFpCkCc_DTII8VOtiRe_PdhVlivunjSQVk8ZwipJRNqCuSB9gu0XqBTim0oQMrXYTlk6clKIgzXA7nVRG5IVeJa3JJBLBWmSMxLiJooFtdJag2aL4trzfUjiSbMQEmEJsvIidBWLhr2IBBlSPHtXL2isEFTuA85HHfQz-NEIyVZkEcEvuZg6tJljAv5uSaGC6CKXksQFsvlpEjyT8oNpcwCZZ5oUHiCuNvZ4WG6UtE0nGHZFJ4Ebgy-DpKUGRpdsYjjFho960sDEhgYNg_9_nE6D-cXceiGwJ_l9YrnLw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```perl6
+*.repeated.Set
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZLBTsMwDIbP5Cl8YhurqiRN00zTJnHgxg3EpcphEpk0qUC1lgNCPHtJbIeWgxs3iT//ttOHa2enty@4PcNh2t6V19CH0xhey6cwTnvxOQR4DsO4F@L8cYXu8h6G47Ec@u4yrleH1Qa@xc1lgPO6bKUvH17uHzcFbMtWefEztaoAJaPZAkwBjv52cYmm41JHc/SbTxrejn5aqnhReoADGNEqhRBLV2aORjxS8hrjlKbMyZdIi18XWZBwtWjjvYZUxVsVArXk@BrTOAK7BVgvwKm8nc84rLQha6g@h14SUHEnqKoauRYVJaqhKEniGKcpmAE1MgwFo8yaWG427jH3DeVVnnES422WkEvArdws2iNx1ICU3fx1LauzNArufk7FU3MEZ0OlFUvMLaPCoqvzZOmB4Cn3ouLS1azVIIKFchsxj/xXrMViWZzkY36F/GZ4wvnAkdvMnUyP0c@j4NnzOCSJMAu0plkYytIs9DnWlh6FT7hf)

Pretty self explanatory. An anonymous code block that gets the count (`+`) of the `Set` of elements among the `repeated` elements of the input (`*`).

I've realised I've posted almost the [exact same solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/174605/76162) for a related question.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 63 bytes

```python
lambda l:len(C(l)-C({*l}))
from collections import Counter as C
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZPbboMwDIav16fwKk3ARKUQAqSVuOIxul6wDjSkFCqgk6Zpz84S2xkgmZw//7aT@/f8OfTp0pZvi6lv7x81mJNp@rAKTXSowp9X8xtFu3YcbnAdjGmuczf0E3S3@zDOUA2Pfm5GqCeolnYY4VpPTQxftXk00PVw3p3PSQyJsJbHoGLQNDraxpq0TWZN09CvFDxt@65J7UZxiQHUJXbABDE5bVpJEh0gx7f2ZCLJt@sL5Nm/djT7ZQi0OwtSZveliJSCCRk60oTWG7TcoF2IR0QSEOMtyAqKUmPPiUg5HxRbhuQcVTmuolOCBXqgpOOMyJCi6DhKzYimV@Ncc/5QYuqgBBRIyL0MHwhO@aTRHAmkNDj/as0effl/UbgO3h1XUBOeDdWmLNOnjoKzXblWma4LrnNOUk5AsupVCGGxnE70JLYh5z5kFih4A99KvkFcbb@gqVusGXWXkyLnovBN4MIIEqI2cElVUeSn2GjUrM9dEMt0wMtp93Qfu34O9234cijUFEG5hxd@U23o2igOyjKArvVjKEt@bo2ZGgiey4DfX7T8AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit prefix function using [Jonah's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/180302/count-repetitions-of-an-array/180303#comment434677_180309).

```apl
+/1<∪⍧⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZI9TgMxEIX7nGL7bBT/7dorpaMhFRLhApF2QxMBBQWpkSKElAgKbkBDxR04ii@yjOeN8VJ4/TP7vnkz9vZhv@gP2/397WJ4ehzu@qEfx/lSr@bLePqML1/jLh7f4ukczx/rq/j6/PNt4/GddpvrC/reXK43467SdaUVjbauXF0F7DqaaBiaGhoB2xzxckzrNFn6Uc2IpFnfIloQhskMyDNJtEHStFYMom8gDMU9jFDUMsgo0TWMDwCGCdBMgKmiLvlR4tUz0UDikdJK2SihYWLLHhLPQcVVGWhE17DUQcO@GiBCGdJH6Q37sURSLG1z0myXj3JDcAY7KDYldugMKmNl5so1BOBksC0rfuo/mcfSEAmXzQEp1UqJuhhzrBZX0iVOof4XJZaUROQxyf3LreVAwNKXZqU3NcMz7Mp9KSR2E6ZBnx3wfuIpiJ90z78)

`+/` the total number occurrences
  <sup>literally the sum of Truths</sup>

`1<` where one is less than

`∪` the unique elements'

`⍧` count in

`⊢` the unmodified argument

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
f(h:t)=sum[1|filter(==h)t==[h]]+f t
f _=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVJBboMwEDyHV/jQQ6JyMMZgU8kvQajiEAQqRFFCbv07Xe@sC@q5h2WN1zM7s/bYP7@u87xtw3n8WC/h@Vra4nuY5vX6OIcwXtYQ2rHr3ge1ZoP6DHpb@ummgro/ptuq3tTS39VAuc1Oqi1yVWiKOlc2Vx5/DSUKQ6mi8PhNFSfbtI6ppIO6y075/3IVzFCjvpMY5maKlAlUGLSNa81U9PVMRCccxFC9ZCqjBVlxAw9Kf6A0B8roqoEmLYodcxqAHNqWYh5GKuasWUdktECJNwOUICsGW6BYWwUSv4fMU2bEmkrm0gyuU@MkmrfSYLAHSbAcW9s0IThkbOKWK/EglGBppWhKg4ETWhrmwtVzSSyXYrTYxVnGizKZFjfRf62JLC01eVzyGuQGU8Fj6fahxTf2@zCb/e40mtsDq8HELRq4gy4vmuKdd932Aw)

Count suffixes where the first element `h` appears exactly once in the part `t` that comes after.

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f l=length$nub$l\\nub l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVIxcoMwEKzNK1RQMhkhCSQKdynzA9sFmbFjJoIwNnk/Od2eApM6xXFCp93bPenePz@vMa7rMM5fj0W99kv/8jY8l@Km4jFep4/lXk7f72U8nympuI79MKmjmh/DtKhSjf2sbpRPxUGd6krVmqKtlKtUwF9HicJQaigCfnPFyzatU7J0UF@KQ/W/XDUztKhvJIa5mSJnAtUGbdNaMxV9AxPRCQ8xVLdMZbQgG24QQBl2lGZHmVx10KRFsWdOA5BHWyvmYaRhzpZ1JEYHlHgzQAmyYbADirU1IAlbyDxlRqzJMpdmcJsbZ9G8lQeDPUiC5dTa5QnBIWMzt1xJAKEES7OiKQ8GTmhpmAtXzyWxbMVovYlzjBdlMi1uov9aE1laavK45DXIDeZCwNJvQ0tv7PdhdtvdaTR3O1aDiTs08DtdQTSlO79c1h8)

Stealing the method from other answers.

Comment: Dammit, we had the exact same answer

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, 41 bytes

```
f[]=0
f(a:s)=sum[1|filter(==a)s==[a]]+f s
```

This solution basically counts how many elements of the list have the same element appear exactly once later in the list.

Answer (score 3):

## PHP, 39 bytes

a nice occasion to use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php):

```php
foreach($argv as$v)$r+=++$$v==2;echo$r;
```

takes input from command line arguments. Run with `-nr` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/081554dada9f6dac7b07a632e62d82ad8b1e746c).

---

`$argv[0]` is `-` and that appears only once in the arguments, so it does not affect the result.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 47 bytes

```hs
f[]=0
f(a:b)|x<-filter(/=a)b,x/=b=1+f x|1>0=f b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Py061taAK00j0SpJs6bCRjctM6cktUhD3zZRM0mnQt82ydZQO02hosbQzsA2TSHpf25iZp5tQVFmXolKWrShDggaAaExEBvqmAChQex/AA)

This is the naïve approach.  There is likely something that could be done to improve this.

```hs
f[]=0
```

We return `0` for the empty list

```hs
f(a:b)
```

In the case of a non-empty list starting with `a` and then `b`.

```hs
|x<-filter(/=a)b,x/=b=1+f x
```

If filtering `a` out of `b` is different from `b` (that is `a` is in `b`) then we return 1 more than `f` applied to `b` with the `a`s filtered out.

```hs
|1>0=f b
```

If filtering `a`s doesn't change `b` then we just run `f` across the rest.

Here is another similar approach that has the same length:

```hs
f[]=0
f(a:b)|elem a b=1+f(filter(/=a)b)|1>0=f b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/Py061taAK00j0SpJsyY1JzVXIVEhydZQO00jLTOnJLVIQ982URMoZWhnYJumkPQ/NzEzz7agKDOvRCUt2lAHBI2A0BiIDXVMgNAg9j8A)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map(o=x=>n+=(o[x]=-~o[x])==2,n=0)|n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i5RLzexQCPftsLWLk/bViM/uiLWVrcORGna2hrp5NkaaNbk/U/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTiDbUUTA0AGIzHQUTHQULCM8SSAGxEZAyBWILCBcmYw4VBrJBlDFQoUGspiYXmsnmQLH/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> <s>9</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
ü èÈÊÉ
```

With lots of help from @ASCII-Only, and suggestions from @Shaggy and @Luis felipe De jesus Munoz.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AehcMrDncc7jrc@f9/tKGOgqEBEJvpKJjoKFhAeJZACoiNgJQpEFtAuDAZc6gwkA2ijIEKDWIB)

Comment: [11](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/wHoXDKyKq63Qjcmr//6821FEwNABiMx0FEx0FCwjPEkgBsRGQMgViCwgXJmMOFQayQZQxUKFBLQA)

Comment: [9](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/wHoXDK@JzFHQN//@vNtRRMDQAYjMdBRMdBQsIzxJIAbERkDIFYgsIFyZjDhUGskGUMVChQS0A) [9](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/wHoXDK@KLDRUK//@vNtRRMDQAYjMdBRMdBQsIzxJIAbERkDIFYgsIFyZjDhUGskGUMVChQS0A) [9?](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/wHoXcHIXDK3QN//@vNtRRMDQAYjMdBRMdBQsIzxJIAbERkDIFYgsIFyZjDhUGskGUMVChQS0A)

Comment: [8](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/wHoXDK@JzFA53/v9fbaijYGgAxGY6CiY6ChYQniWQAmIjIGUKxBYQLkzGHCoMZIMoY6BCg1oA) [8](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/wHoXcHIXDKw53/v9fbaijYGgAxGY6CiY6ChYQniWQAmIjIGUKxBYQLkzGHCoMZIMoY6BCg1oA)

Comment: [7](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/3@/wHoWcw50KOf//VxvqKBgaALGZjoKJjoIFhGcJpIDYCEiZArEFhAuTMYcKA9kgyhio0KAWAA) [maybe 6 but probably not](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AehZzDnQo5//9HVxvqKBgaALGZjoKJjoIFhGcJpIDYCEiZArEFhAuTMYcKA9kgyhio0KA2FgA)

Comment: [6](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AehZzDnQo5//9HG@ooGBoAsZmOgomOggWEZwmkgNgISJkCsQWEC5MxhwoD2SDKGKjQIBYA)

Comment: [6](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AehdzDrYdX5Pz/H22oo2BoAMRmOgomOgoWEJ4lkAJiIyBlCsQWEC5MxhwqDGSDKGOgQoNYAA) [6](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AehdzDXYdXHO78/z/aUEfB0ACIzXQUTHQULCA8SyAFxEZAyhSILSBcmIw5VBjIBlHGQIUGsQA)

Comment: Welcome to Japt! :) If you weren't aware, there's currently [an open bounty for Japt solutions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17410/58974). @ASCII-only got you about as low as you can get on this one but another alternative that's closest to your original solution would be [`ü èÈÊÉ`](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///AehcMrDncc7jrc@f9/tKGOgqEBEJvpKJjoKFhAeJZACoiNgJQpEFtAuDAZc6gwkA2ijIEKDWIB).

Comment: [Another 6 bytes =D](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=/CCuyj4x&input=WzIzNCwgMiwgMTIsIDIzNCwgNSwgMTAsIDEwMDAsIDIsIDk5LCAyMzRdIC14). Welcome to Japt c:

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks :) I need to start remembering/figuring out all these shortcuts :)

Answer (score 2):

## Wolfram Language 34 bytes

```
 Length@DeleteCases[Gather@#,{x_}]&
```

`Gather` groups identical integers into lists.
`DeleteCases[...{x_}]` eliminates lists containing a single number.
`Length` returns the number of remaining lists (each containing two or more identical integers.

Comment: `Count[{_,__}]@*Gather`

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 6 bytes

```
l{.-Q{
```

[Try it here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%7B.-Q%7B&input=%5B1%2C%2010%2C%2016%2C%204%2C%208%2C%2010%2C%209%2C%2019%2C%202%2C%2015%2C%2018%2C%2019%2C%2010%2C%209%2C%2017%2C%2015%2C%2019%2C%205%2C%2013%2C%2020%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input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debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
l{.-Q{
     {Q   Deduplicate the (implicit) input.
  .-Q     Remove the first instance of each from the input.
l{        Count unique.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
ọzt;1xl
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVI5TsRAEPyKH@BgTs@seIrlgCWAYCUkhMSRQUDGJ3gB@T6BV7AfMT1VNbIJ2nO0q7qqe44P1zd3L6f727BePr4v728/X0/r7/nz9fHKP5/WdZ79OHhnMY1DGofK08EWi2BLtqg89kzRte3bEu1Ht4yz98BPzG4UAcwg6KtBfGDRtncgsm81GssXCrFsBFFwwmXQVxLWHWHYETZHh6bHSWsBYyCksGSUbVrIYJygofElouAqECNcBjQRA12ZFHUL9VG9gZ5oTA7QqRftcnHVG8I7yqHZVjixM3QGZOfVGCrpFJAVpac3hC5sG4yJw0ZCVqMs@k1YAlqq1CWUcP9NSZJTRo9J89fUeqJyW7ZmtTfVvGmQarVj4bTjDOxzIn3ZaarS0@a8LH8)

Explanation:

```
ọ          For every unique element E of the input, [E, how many times E occurs]
 zt        The last elements of the previous value.
   ;1x     With every 1 removed,
      l    how many there are.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 6 bytes

```
e:uDul
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/P9Wq1KU05///aCNjEwUjBUMjBRDDVMHQAIgMDIBClpYgoVgA)

```
e	| eval as a list
 :	| duplicate
  u	| uniquify
   D	| multiset difference; keep only repeated elements
    u	| uniquify
     l	| find length
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>49</s> 31 bytes

```
$=>[tally&|enumerate[k,v]->v>1]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?IGYI8n)

-18 bytes due to Arturo 0.9.83 providing `tally` and `enumerate`.

```
$ => [               ; a function
    tally &          ; create a dictionary of elements and their occurrences from the input
    |                ; then...
    enumerate[k,v]-> ; count the number of key-value pairs where...
    v>1              ; the value (occurrences) is greater than one
]                    ; end function
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
ĐỤ⇹ɔ⁻žŁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISHu5c8at95csqjxt1H9x1t/P8/2kxHwURHwdAQiEG0uY6CMYQCCRkBKTOoDIQHRKZQDOIaQLUaxwIA)

```
Đ             implicit input; Đuplicate on the stack
 Ụ            get Ụnique elements
  ⇹ɔ          ɔount occurrences of each in original list
    ⁻žŁ       decrement; remove žeros; get Łength; implicit print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
Uæc1Q
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVUlQzMlQTZjMVEmZm9vdGVyPSZpbnB1dD0lNUIxJTJDJTIwMTklMkMlMjAxNyUyQyUyMDE3JTJDJTIwMCUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAxNCUyQyUyMDEwJTJDJTIwMTAlMkMlMjAxMiUyQyUyMDUlMkMlMjAxNCUyQyUyMDE2JTJDJTIwNyUyQyUyMDE1JTJDJTIwMTUlMkMlMjAxOCUyQyUyMDExJTJDJTIwMTclMkMlMjA3JTVEJmZsYWdzPUw=)

##### Explanation

```python
Uæc1Q  # Implicit input
U      # Uniquify the input
 æ     # Filter it by:
  c    #  Count in the input
   1Q  #  Is not equal to 1
       # Push the length
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Element](https://github.com/PhiNotPi/Element), 40 bytes

```
_(#'{"2:0+4:'~1+";~2=[''1+""]$2+'[(#]'}`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S81JzU3NK/n/P15DWb1aycjKQNvESr3OUFvJus7INlpdHchSilUx0laP1lCOVa9N@P8/2kBHwVhHwUxHwVBHwVRHwQjIgHDMwBKGRmAOSAwoawImQfLmYI5FLAA)

This requires input to be in a precise format like `[234, 2, 1000, 2, 99, 234]` (enclosed with `[]` with a comma and space between integers).

**Explanation:**

```
_                                        input
 (#                                      delete the [ at start of input
   '{"                               '}  WHILE the string is non-empty
   '{"2:                             '}    duplicate it
   '{"  0+                           '}    add 0 to coerce to integer (gets next number in array)
   '{"    4:                         '}    make 3 additional copies
   '{"      '                        '}    temporarily move 1 copy to control stack
   '{"       ~                       '}    fetch the current map value for given integer
   '{"        1+                     '}    increment map value
   '{"          "                    '}    retrieve temporary copy of integer (the key for the map)
   '{"           ;                   '}    store updated map value
   '{"            ~                  '}    fetch map value again (1 if 1st instance, 2 if 2nd, etc.)
   '{"             2=                '}    test for map value = 2, this is the first duplication
   '{"               [      ]        '}    IF
   '{"               [''    ]        '}      move stuff from main stack to control stack
   '{"               [  1+  ]        '}      increment the counter of duplicate (bottom of stack)
   '{"               [    ""]        '}      move stuff back to main stack
   '{"                       $       '}    take length of current integer
   '{"                        2+     '}    add 2 (for the comma and space)
   '{"                          '[  ]'}    FOR loop with that number
   '{"                          '[(#]'}      trim those many characters from front of input string
                                       ` output result
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>59</s> 54 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
$l=sum[1\\[_,_:_]<-group(sort l)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85JTcz7n5ufUpqTqpCbmJn3PzO3IL@oRCG4JMU1r0wHSPlkJnGp5NgWl@ZGG8bERMfrxFvFx9rophfllxZoFIPU5mjG/g8uSQSybBVUFKKNjE10FIx0FAyBGMw2BbINQNjAACxhaQmWiP3/LzktJzG9@L@up89/l8q8xNzMZAgHYi0A)

Sorts the list, groups adjacent equal elements, and counts the number with more than 1 item.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 19 bytes

```
O`.+
m`^(.+)(¶\1)+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVI7TsVADOz3FClAylOip/1m/SqOQEGLUCgoKKBA72wcgIsFr2dW2cJZx5sZz9j5@bh/fr8fj/PLvk5Px/N@XdzX/jZfl8v89/saLsvDcYR1Cl5jW6e8ToK3mx4aUY@iIXjtN5VlzduR9EPvQjD0hruTIBqvwfupgBDRsuXeaPQpTm8rROhdMproiSpGLqCTgS4OdM3NzZmhiqiwIZa1domGIb4Y32b9G1sGSv1EIIgqBsxAmKYCAjmD8@NMTEty3oBbb9iFWqkPAjVIgc3WttE5ODJc5@ToBWQMk5SopQ8CDjSNDuu1Mi0mmgunqGxYKuJ0rIEf7VCOZ50/DzfOTfULQVrPIbV/yFFd35FH0zwwRkw3g7wOeoRa2m7/AQ) Link includes test suite which splits each line on commas. Explanation:

```
O`.+
```

Sort equal values together.

```
m`^(.+)(¶\1)+$
```

Count the number of runs of at least two values.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
lf<1/QT.{Q
```

Probably a way to golf it, I'm quite rusty with pyth...

Alternate 10 byte version...

```
lf>lT1.gSk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PyfNxlA/MESvOvD//2gjYxMdBSMdBUMgBrNNgWwDEDYwAEtYWoIlYgE)

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 126 bytes

```
let f=|v:Vec<i32>|{let mut u=v.clone();u.sort();u.dedup();u.iter().filter(|i|v.iter().filter(|n|**n==**i).count()>1).count()};
```

I give up.  This is basically the same as Ruby. There is "another way" creating an array and indexing into it using the values in the input vector, +100000, however the type conversions (as usize / as i32) take up too much space.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 33 bytes

```powershell
($args|group|?{$_.Count-1}).Count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZPxaoMwEMb/9ylC54aCHTHRGgdjhT1IKZvtBtI6tWzQ9tldct@lZitoL7m7X767nN3xu@mHj6Ztp3gnnsV5SuJtvx8u@/546i4v53jz@Ho8HcZlfk1hTdcoWieRsL8sUZlQurCvTOTeLq0t3SMlOeqaHCmn2IicI1aZsCuDlY3Ka5AcwWDpPRVv1@BrGyg90W3kxFkhakYpOoFA/l9Dqjvc2ZKA9m0CnI2rIMxGaVoryfklHWMANgFYBWBXYR3qk1xDRWSF1AoSNPtRWknkFWly3AJZf6pVyOX8khAFcklnCZSZH@4z9470aU/EWRrto0xfBm35hmEP8tAEJ6AIOlf4yongz@FrM7cpoUmRrMSAzGkVTBVIw5BQALdCc@n5LBRDxSq5i3SU/F9seWusgiXnYeS54Vv2DgOzmpvpZjK8Dh4AvhJMPUnyCIX7KHBMFWg0rM/NRRql4iLuxZnQcfPTNW9j854J@0n29uOMN3D0zXBqR7vxYL/ZtfPdiaFrt@P4edhTyCJOOGrZfN1A6ZPPXUTX6Rc)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
8#uqz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/30K5tLDq//9oI2MTHQUjHQVDIAazTYFsAxA2MABLWFqCJWIB) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##VVK7bsNADNv7FQa6erinT9nzCd2CAO3eDgHSpT/vSCQPdgf5HjIpUrqfr@f3/rnb@@/jb79@7Le8Ljl5bOvS1sV4uvjiUXzpHsbjzAxd@z6W6j@m@9stZ@A3Zg@KAmYQzNUhubBo7BOI/GtO4/lBIZ6tICpJuA56I6GdCMuJMBxdQk@S1gHGQshgySrbtNDBuEFD8DWi4KoQI1wHtBEDXZ0UdoT6qN5AT3WmBOg2i065uJoN4R3l0GwUbuwMnQE5eTUGI50Csqr0zIbQhW@LM3HYSMhqlcV8CGtAS5W6hBLpvylJSsroMWn@mtpMGLfjaFa8qfCmQarViYXbibOwz43046TJpCfmfH8B).

#### Explanation

```
8#u   % Number of ocurrences of each unique value
q     % Subtract 1
z     % Number of nonzeros
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP (112 Bytes)

```
<?php $c=0;foreach(array_count_values(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://stdin'))) as $b)if($b>1)$c++;echo $c;
```

The assignment does not make it clear if the input is received via Stdin in exactly given format or as separate parameters in Argv, so here is a variant for argv, 91 Bytes:

```
<?php array_shift($argv);$c=0;foreach(array_count_values($argv) as $b)if($b>1)$c++;echo $c;
```

Comment: Yes, you can take input via the command line arguments (as per [standard IO](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2449/76162) formats). Though wouldn't there be problems if the filename was numerical?

Comment: @JoKing Sure, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 8 bytes

```
lfthTr8S
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lfthTr8S&input=%5B234%2C%202%2C%2012%2C%20234%2C%205%2C%2010%2C%201000%2C%202%2C%2099%2C%20234%5D&debug=0), or verify all the test cases at once [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=lfthTr8S&test_suite=1&test_suite_input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debug=0).

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 42 bytes

```
: d ( x -- ) duplicates members length . ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVFLTsMwEN33FG8JiyLb@dntAVA33SAOUFIDldq0JK4Eqjh7mDduUCGyksl43mdmXjdtOvbj89Nq/bjAED/OsWvjIFEacOpjSl@nftclLGer9QLt8dylcYEt7vCJ@Rz32J5P@127SQI6xMNL7AfsY/eW3vGA5XiBK0o4WKdBBWvkGCOpEDT1je3sAqsXNUp4RgE2ECX1nmFONZoIZCngDCasFVDNuyvMCQ1B@V1QXKglMAI1UswnYwMaKtYoJBRKAioh86TwE4WbKCx/f3WNWmqEwrG4oUShaVqshKKGUpasMrjRFT6FCqISTMlyylfILevRYWizFC4mrBFArRrZFOieBvlHVTYg3OW10z@6No8oU@o0fV4PN2RUy5NJ6xp@3YTldpjXbgp1b68WJAU1oH2Tzfz3rLIm758Y3ZVOO2c88jh9DsONZ91Bk2foVCxDHIdVkqyZlL3KciWCHX8A)

Answer (score 1):

### k, 8 bytes

`+/1<#:'=`

reads as: sum (length each group) > 1

```
+/ is sum (plus over)

#:' is length each

= is group (ex. =1 2 1 6 7 2 generates 1 2 6 7!(0 2;1 5;,3;,4) (dictionary of unique value and its positions)
```

Use example (first test case)

```
+/1<#:'=1 10 16 4 8 10 9 19 2 15 18 19 10 9 17 15 19 5 13 20
```

writes 4

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-ap`, 35 bytes

```perl
map$k{$_}++,@F;$_=grep$_>1,values%k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlu1olvlZbW8fBzVol3ja9KLVAJd7OUKcsMac0tVg1@/9/Q0MFBUNLBQUjBQVjIAvEM4WIWIAFDaHYyABIg1QAhQ2hCoGKzCFMo3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6yYWAAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ëB♀╡╙
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=89420cb5d3&i=[1,+10,+16,+4,+8,+10,+9,+19,+2,+15,+18,+19,+10,+9,+17,+15,+19,+5,+13,+20]%0A[11,+8,+6,+15,+9,+19,+2,+2,+4,+19,+14,+19,+13,+12,+16,+13,+0,+5,+0,+8]%0A[9,+7,+8,+16,+3,+9,+20,+19,+15,+6,+8,+4,+18,+14,+19,+12,+12,+16,+11,+19]%0A[10,+17,+17,+7,+2,+18,+7,+13,+3,+10,+1,+5,+15,+4,+6,+0,+19,+4,+17,+0]%0A[12,+7,+17,+13,+5,+3,+4,+15,+20,+15,+5,+18,+18,+18,+4,+8,+15,+13,+11,+13]%0A[0,+3,+6,+1,+5,+2,+16,+1,+6,+3,+12,+1,+16,+5,+4,+5,+6,+17,+4,+8]%0A[11,+19,+2,+3,+11,+15,+19,+8,+2,+12,+12,+20,+13,+18,+1,+11,+19,+7,+11,+2]%0A[6,+4,+11,+14,+17,+3,+17,+11,+2,+16,+14,+1,+2,+1,+15,+15,+12,+10,+11,+13]%0A[0,+19,+2,+0,+10,+10,+16,+9,+19,+9,+15,+0,+10,+18,+0,+17,+18,+18,+0,+9]%0A[1,+19,+17,+17,+0,+2,+14,+10,+10,+12,+5,+14,+16,+7,+15,+15,+18,+11,+17,+7]&a=1&m=2)

Answer (score 1):

## Japt `-x`, 5 bytes

```
ü ®¦q
```

[Run it online](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=/CCupnE=&input=WzAsIDMsIDYsIDEsIDUsIDIsIDE2LCAxLCA2LCAzLCAxMiwgMSwgMTYsIDUsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDE3LCA0LCA4XSAgICAKCi14)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
LuṠ-u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/36f04c4FuqX///@PNjTSMdcxBCJjHVMdYx0THUNTHSMDEGmqY2gBRSY6FiARoBpDQyAZCwA)

```
L        The number of
 u       unique elements of
  Ṡ-u    the input with every unique element removed once.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 71 bytes

```c
f(r,l,t)int*r;{int n[7<<15]={};for(t=0;l;t+=!~n[r[--l]+100000]--);r=t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZTJboMwFEX3fAWNVAkKlmwzOXL4EsqiSpUKKaUVYYfor9M3OURdNooHbO7xfc82Z/VxPm/bJZnyaz6nwzi/TH6BJh675nQyVd8uq798Tcncan/1c9Y@/Yzd1Cl17TOj8dcrlfqpnf26fb4NY5IuUYSE6db1ndVAiBaTx0ZDqfO4zGPHT0dooFhoKiiOH8NMI8PQx6aAF/WaA8oQoObpnWEJTYTQgsZYXhX7mkhQO@TACw1bgemCSFaLsCK@Y6J7INoHIsZ0JEda7DaEtKxpeNFCIucoKkLW5AKBJas4MMsiEVakLVlEzipmuL1ILiU/5KhAlCZtHZYNjmkoJIXH2BDHiyuXkh2OjqSBLJvhmCeFjBXiKCSF44CuRRTvOc1IuIVEaXZrJcnFl2SK1tB/4hJTWqbkUMkxkL0LE467zZ4wPFsUnuyn5Fvz0uUD1HKyS@Y3D66cOMLdBhbD/vdHKwo6Cs0oJCqxoyz2S6z0vcKx6j4OthQpqnvlsDIB1azR6qMIby/exwFu8HAy1g9ZBnf0e4LBS3J4fn8dDzl8AW7d0OdWp6mPQLj9Ag)

Naive approach. `7<<15`=229376.

Comment: [70 bytes](https://tio.run/##jVPLboMwELz3K9pIlaCsJa/BYOTwJZRDlSoVUkorwg3RX0931kTqsSEGs9p57MQ5mY/T6XY7ZzNd8nFaXua4yuNx6pvjkf3QrRstnY3nrzmLl7gU3dPP1M@9MZehYIvPYEwe526J222@9kPvrKAeVia2xDVVFLBriVtyxJ44YJtKjRZakltJzm4kOBZAjfoOcUIBQLqXxA60srECsxQAaqmBTE2loJzVTi8sAdhwx7o7Vry1qmXVQiNoh74GtKUahyUv6JqUrUJX8udIIdLppbdCGxQ9pdH0q0PrUNAqgbPSXCtv8kAwCz94gxL8Cm@VJlKP0poYNKRAbp8BeqVKpVngiMkBh8BRU8OlGuVdUUqkejoamOxfeypntag/nMavOaZKoJRWSNsUoOaqeVhwV3e4QxoVaJq7XlAxyXoH/udCq2EyomIEalTHONlUsuy@5N3vpZoM2vy@gixO0GZ72GiMn2/jlOWrnufxyC7m37Mc@HN2eH5/nQ4k/4RrPxbFICHnuZzpXw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
UÞ⊍UL
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQIiwiIiwiVcOe4oqNVUwiLCIiLCJbMjM0LCAyLCAxMiwgMjM0LCA1LCAxMCwgMTAwMCwgMiwgOTksIDIzNF0iXQ==)

Typical symmetric difference with the unique values in the list, take the length of the unique values in that list.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
Ċċ∑t
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLEisSL4oiRdCIsIiIsIlsxLCAxMCwgMTYsIDQsIDgsIDEwLCA5LCAxOSwgMiwgMTUsIDE4LCAxOSwgMTAsIDksIDE3LCAxNSwgMTksIDUsIDEzLCAyMF0iXQ==)

Just another 4 byter

### Explained

```
Ċċ∑t­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
Ċ     # ‎⁡[[item, count(item)] for item in input]
 ċ    # ‎⁢Each item != 1?
  ∑   # ‎⁣Summate. Because this is implemented as reduce by addition, it vectorises element-wise when folding.
   t  # ‎⁤Get the last item of that (the number of counts that != 1)
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 93 bytes

```javascript
a=>Object.values(a.reduce((a,c)=>Object.assign(a,{[c]:(a[c]|0)+1}),{})).filter(i=>i>1).length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5BDoIwELz7Co5trA1FBdTAF3wA4VBLwZIGDAUuyNtxKaKJ8TA7u7ObmS15z41o1KPdVXUmpzyaeBRfb6UULe257qRBnDYy64REiBOBP1tujCoq0IZEpGfEoT5dvGUjJsOIMc2VbmWDVBSrmGGqZVW090nUlam1pLouUI4SRhzmAnziHIgTLtMJCOABHQHhMq6b4C1DP9MeDt0U48vmxzr4JzJmU/zF4xvk2XwbszIYM295be5dGwc1nH2nFw)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 67 bytes

```javascript
a=>[...new Set(a.filter(e=>a.indexOf(e)!=a.lastIndexOf(e)))].length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NDoIwEITvPkW9tQluKP6AMXD35MEj4dDAgpimNdCob48LFU2Mh@nsTpv5elV31Zdde3MrYysc6nRQaZYDgMEHO6PjCupWO@w4ppmC1lT4PNUcxTJVoFXvjp9EiAI0msZdhtKa3moEbRte81wGTIakXcA2AUv8ticjRWRbUuLX@SZ@xzSPtqaHYSHEYfFTHf8LpZwoO9/xBUUTf8LMTsUy8l8b53DC0ZmMvcML)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS), 9 chars, 18 bytes

```
{≢∪⍵∼⍦∪⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{≢∪⍵∼⍦∪⍵}
  f 1 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 1
2
  f 234, 2, 12, 234, 5, 10, 1000, 2, 99, 234
2
  f 1, 10, 16, 4, 8, 10, 9, 19, 2, 15, 18, 19, 10, 9, 17, 15, 19, 5, 13, 20
4
  f 11, 8, 6, 15, 9, 19, 2, 2, 4, 19, 14, 19, 13, 12, 16, 13, 0, 5, 0, 8
5
```