# There's more than one way to skin a set

Tags: code-golf, number, set-partitions, integer-partitions

Given a set of positive integers \$ S \$, output the set of all positive integers \$ n \$ such that \$ n \$ can be made by summing a subset of \$ S \$ in more than one different way, i.e., that are the sums of more than one subset of \$ S \$.

To be clear, a subset of \$ S \$ means that you can't use numbers from \$ S \$ more than once.

### Example

For example, given \$ S = \{2, 3, 5, 6\} \$, the following numbers can be made:

- \$ 2 = \sum\{2\} \$
- \$ 3 = \sum\{3\} \$
- \$ 5 = \sum\{5\} = \sum\{2, 3\} \$
- \$ 6 = \sum\{6\} \$
- \$ 7 = \sum\{2, 5\} \$
- \$ 8 = \sum\{2, 6\} = \sum\{3, 5\} \$
- \$ 9 = \sum\{3, 6\} \$
- \$ 10 = \sum\{2, 3, 5\} \$
- \$ 11 = \sum\{5, 6\} = \sum\{2, 3, 6\} \$
- \$ 13 = \sum\{2, 5, 6\} \$
- \$ 14 = \sum\{3, 5, 6\} \$
- \$ 16 = \sum\{2, 3, 5, 6\} \$

Of these, only \$ 5 \$, \$ 8 \$, and \$ 11 \$ can be made in more than one way. Therefore, `[5, 8, 11]` is the output.

### Rules

- The input will be non-empty and contain no duplicate numbers
- Output may be in any order, but it must not contain duplicate numbers
- You may use any [standard I/O method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1061) are forbidden
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
[1]                   -> []
[4, 5, 2]             -> []
[9, 10, 11, 12]       -> [21]
[2, 3, 5, 6]          -> [5, 8, 11]
[15, 16, 7, 1, 4]     -> [16, 20, 23, 27]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]       -> [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 7):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 15 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
(1=⊒)⊸/·⥊(∾∾+)˝
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgKDE94oqSKeKKuC/Ct+KliijiiL7iiL4rKcudCgriiJjigL8x4qWKRsKoIOKfqArin6gx4p+pCuKfqDQsIDUsIDLin6kK4p+oOSwgMTAsIDExLCAxMuKfqQrin6gyLCAzLCA1LCA24p+pCuKfqDE1LCAxNiwgNywgMSwgNOKfqQrin6gxLCAyLCAzLCA0LCA14p+pCuKfqQ==)

---

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), 19 bytes<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/mlochbaum/BQN/blob/master/commentary/sbcs.bqn)</sup>

```
(1=⊒)⊸/<+´∘×¨⟜⥊⟜↕2¨
```

[Run online!](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=RiDihpAgKDE94oqSKeKKuC88K8K04oiYw5fCqOKfnOKliuKfnOKGlTLCqAoK4oiY4oC/MeKlikbCqCDin6gK4p+oMeKfqQrin6g0LCA1LCAy4p+pCuKfqDksIDEwLCAxMSwgMTLin6kK4p+oMiwgMywgNSwgNuKfqQrin6gxNSwgMTYsIDcsIDEsIDTin6kK4p+oMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNeKfqQrin6k=)

`2¨` A 2 for each value in the input array.
`↕` Indices of an array of shape 2 × ... × 2. These are all combinations of 0's and 1's of the length of the input.
`⥊` Flatten into a list of lists.
`<   ×¨` Multiply each of the indices with the input element-wise.
`+´` Take the sum of each result.
`(1=⊒)⊸/` Keep only elements which occur the second time.

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
Set@@@Gather[Tr/@Subsets@#]⋃{}&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7875@W5hCcWmJlVZxaUpRYzpVm@x/IdXBwcAcpKooOKdJ3CC5NAsoWOyjHPupurq5V@x9QlJlXEq2sa5cGFFOrC05OzKur5qo2rNXhqjbRMdUxAjEsdQwNdAwNdQzBPCMdY6CEGYhpaKpjaKZjrmOoY1LLVfsfAA)

```
             Tr/@Subsets@#      subset sums
      Gather[             ]     group by value
Set@@@                          drop first per group and join
                           ⋃{}  union (unique)
```

In normal usage, `Set` is just assignment, e.g. `Set[a,1]` ~ `a=1`, returning the assigned value. Importantly,

- It always returns that assigned value, even when the assignment target is invalid, and
- When called with ≠2 arguments, it reasonably interprets that as assigning a target to a `Sequence` of the remaining arguments, i.e. `Set[a,1,2]` ~ `a=Sequence[1,2]`. 
  <sub>(On a side note, Mathics does *not* do this, possibly because `Set` already has `SequenceHold`)</sub>

Together, these mean that `Set` can (usually) replace `##2&` to save one byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
ṗṠsĠ~Ḣvh
```

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLhuZfhuaBzxKB+4biidmgiLCIiLCJbMTUsIDE2LCA3LCAxLCA0XSJd) or [run all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQaiIsIsabIiwi4bmX4bmgc8SgfuG4onZoIiwiO1rGm2AgPT4gYGoiLCJbWzFdLCBbNCwgNSwgMl0sIFs5LCAxMCwgMTEsIDEyXSwgWzIsIDMsIDUsIDZdLCBbMTUsIDE2LCA3LCAxLCA0XV0iXQ==).

`sĠ~Ḣvh` is the shortest way I can think of to keep only duplicates, so...

`~Ḣvh` could alternatively be `vḢfU` for same byte count.

### How?

```
ṗṠsĠ~Ḣvh
ṗ        # Powerset of (implicit) input
 Ṡ       # Sum of each
  s      # Sort
   Ġ     # Group consecutive identical items
    ~    # Filter for:
     Ḣ   #  Remove the head (this means if it is only one item long, it will be falsey, else truthy)
      vh # Get the first item of each
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 66 bytes

```
\(S,t=table(unlist(Map(\(i)combn(S,i,sum),seq(!S)))))names(t[t>1])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY3nWI0gnVKbEsSk3JSNUrzcjKLSzR8Ews0YjQyNZPzc5PygNKZOsWluZo6xamFGorBmiCQl5ibWqxREl1iZxirCTVpT5pGsoahpqayAibQtVOIjuUCKTDRUTDVUTBCV4ZQYKmjYGgAxIZAjKQMpMDIEKLESEfBGGyMGYoxICVAQQuQZohCQyDX0ExHwRxI6SiYwFSDFIKEjYD2GAFNMjKPhfhhwQIIDQA)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 69 bytes

```javascript
a=>(g=([v,...a],s=0)=>v?g(a,s+v)|g(a,s):(g[s]=-~g[s])-2||print(s))(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BTsMwDIbvfQrfmmhutoSxjVUpJ54i8sGqaBma1qmZclnh1YtTLoCw9Muxv/@P5HdOHNvxdL1V6TB3fmbfqN6rkNAYw4TRb7Rv0nOvGOMq6Wl56KPqQyRffeamKzdN1/F0uamotWI916EACJbgVyGs1xAooy3CI4Kjf9ATgt2IrCgbvpGzC3QID0t0Rz9yMh9yYrFYmewOYS8NYSu@bMkbJ986ibs9FVSYbhhfuH1TDL6Bu0Tb4RKH86s5D70qQwkrYFFJpa6FdnJY/ccliw89fwE)

#### Commented

```javascript
a => (              // a[] = input array
  g = (             // g is a recursive function taking:
    [v,             //   v = next value
        ...a],      //   a[] = remaining values
    s = 0           //   s = sum
  ) =>              //
  v ?               // if v is defined:
    g(a, s + v) |   //   do a recursive call where v is added to s
    g(a, s)         //   do a recursive call where s is left unchanged
  :                 // else:
    (g[s] = -~g[s]) //   using g as an object, increment a counter for
                    //   the sum s
    -2 ||           //   if this is the 2nd time we reach this sum:
      print(s)      //     print it
)(a)                // initial call to g
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>28</sup> 19 bytes

```
[:~.@(#~1-~:)(,,+)/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY0xC8IwEIX3/IqHgkkwTXuXNm0DhYLg5OTqKC3i4mDn/PWYYnU4OL5377tn2lk5YwiQMKgQ8hQWp@vlnG4h2lHtIxUxaGXMUZdJi2V6L4PFdH@8RlWEgypD1Ji1EC0a9PCgCjU6OBCDCGsBBM6gRiOk3Mh/yxQslAlM@kv61ZGrxKLL4U/CxpnGeEEeXIEduN1c@cajzV/q9AE)

*-9 thanks to ovs for the `(,,+)/` trick for calculating all subset sums!*

- `(,,+)/` All subset sums
- `[:(#~1-~:)` Keep only repeats
- `~.@` Dedup

Comment: I think `1#.]#~2#:@i.@^#` can simply be `(,,+)/`. (The order of the output is different)

Comment: Yes!  I think I've used that trick before but had forgot about it.  It's a good one, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
ŒP§œ-Q$Q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIBDy49O1g1UCfx/uP3opIc7Z2hG/v8fbRiroxBtoqNgqqNgBGJa6igYGgCxIRCDBYx0FIzB0mYgniGQYWimo2AOpHQUTMBCOkY6xjomOqaxAA)

### How it works

```
ŒP§œ-Q$Q - Main link. Takes S on the left
ŒP       - Powerset of S
  §      - Sum of each
      $  - To the list of sums:
     Q   -   Deduplicate
   œ-    -   Set difference
       Q - Deduplicate
```

Comment: Exactly what I had!

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 96 bytes

```
n=L.length
S=[total(floor(mod(i/2^{[0...n]},2))L)fori=[0...2^n-1]].sort
f(L)=S[S[2...]=S].unique
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3ldqmbxun8)

#### How it works

Conceptually similar to [Steffan's Vyxal solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/247334/68261) but lacks builtins :)

```py
S=[total(floor(mod(i/2^{[0...n]},2))L)fori=[0...2^n-1]].sort
 for i=[0...2^n-1]                        # Powerset of input as bitmasks
  total(floor(mod(i/2^{[0...n]},2))L)     # Sum of each
  .sort                                   # Sort
f(L)=
 S[        ]        # Filter for:
  S[2...]=S         # Next element is equal to current element
            .unique # Remove duplicates
```

Note on the slice comparison: `S[2...]` is the list `S` except for the first element. Since broadcasting takes the shorter list, `S[2...]=S` is equivalent to `S[2...n]=S[1...n-1]`, or `[{S[i+1] = S[i]} for i=[1...n-1]] = 1`.

Comment: Oh wow this is a smart solution (especially the `S[S[2...]=S]` part, ingenious!), I didn't think about doing it this way.

Comment: @AidenChow that's allowed. Same as when a language uses an int type and can't handle 2^32 as an intermediate value. It's just a lower limit than other languages.

Comment: Ah yep I figured as much.

Comment: Also unrelated to your answer but how do i get `argmin` and `argmax` to work? It is not working for me for some reason.

Comment: @AidenChow let's take this to chat

Answer (score 3):

## [Attache](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Attache), 33 bytes

```
${{_~x>1}\Unique@x}##Sum=>Subsets
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SywpSUzOSP2fpmBl@1@lujq@rsLOsDYmNC@zsDTVoaJWWTm4NNfWLrg0qTi1pPi/X2pqSnG0SkFBcnosV0BRZl5JSGpxiXNicWpxdJqOQjSXAhBEG8bqQBgmOgqmOgpGMK6ljoKhARAbAjFc0EhHwRiszAwmYgjkGJrpKJgDKR0FE7gw0CSwWpCpsVyxsf8B)

*Happy 1,000 answers on this site to me?*

### Explanation

```
${{_~x>1}\Unique@x}##Sum=>Subsets    pure function
                          Subsets    get all Subsets
                     Sum=>           and map Sum to each subset
                   ##                then
${                }                  x = the set of subsets sums
          Unique@x                   get those unique sums
  {     }\                           and filter each sum
   _~x                               ...by counting how often it appears in x
      >1                             ...and asserting it is more than 1
```

### Other approaches

Unfortunately, while there are a few builtins which have similar behavior, wrangling them into a manageable format proves to be too verbose.

**50 bytes:** `Flat@Betail@{Commonest[_,1:#_]^^nil}##Sum=>Subsets`

**39 bytes:** `${{_&Count!x>1}\Unique@x}##Sum=>Subsets`

**38 bytes:** `First=>{_@1@1}\Positions##Sum=>Subsets`

**37 bytes:** `` `@&0=>{_@1@1}\Positions##Sum=>Subsets ``

Comment: Congrats on 1000 answers!

Comment: Thank you! @AidenChow

Answer (score 3):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 48 bytes

```
a->[k-1|c<-Vec(prod(i=!k=0,#a,1+x^a[i])),c>#k++]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LU1BCsIwEPzK2l5SuoGm1qpg-wwvIUqoRkJFQ2lBwZ94KYj4Jn_jJvWwuzOzM7vPj9Od3Z_c-DJQvYfe8NU307yWLRePZsO3x4a57npgtpq1VYaxRpHedlpalSTY1HGbpuqfG7Rz5zvTwGtwnb30BCNPIjBMkx2kFIp6gbBAyD1cI4iMSlAFIUeYh3XpmSAgSoQlDYQiSJQMHn9FqWR6Po7T_AE)

Using generating functions. For input \$\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\$, finds all \$k\$s such that the coefficient of \$x^k\$ in \$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x^{a_i})\$ is greater than \$1\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 37 bytes

```factor
[ all-subsets [ Σ ] map duplicates ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NDoIwFIT3PcVcQGIVMOoBjBs3xhVhUUqNjVAqbReGcBrv45Xq8yc4q5kvLzPvLKTv@ng67g@7DVrhL4ns2kobQVhL90XBaNnVCrZX3t9tr42HU7egjFSOnHfYMjYwkAZwjD@XIsNiSmvwOTgH/6MFlnSST5ln4DlWVJESG1ksIJpm5kL1GSnwfKCknyzqYBsthaf9Mr6B80Jek/gC)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 120 bytes

```hs
g(s,d)i=(i:s,if i`elem`s&&i`notElem`d then i:d else d)
f c=snd.foldl g([],[])$map(sum.zipWith(*)c)(sequence[[0,1]|_<-c])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYsxT8MwFIT3/IobqspGj6oupYiIjAxMHTtYFonil@YJxwk4XRD/PU27keF0@r7TtVX64hCmrpKIPMfHEUpndyrg@wwYfiSOWKGBNe4/7wnPhN3CvhLMdo6Zs9x2hKf76bAYzOzMgfAyF2HvprNK5LUUSvJE0kBKDtyVab2WMvbj@w08xpYjJPfgkBheZw3qIkW/afrgA87KOrJOr7pqUOnSbX5lOMnYqgdda5X4@8KxZmu3ZNzf59tj7fQ0XQE)

- `g :: ([Int], [Int]) -> Int -> ([Int], [Int])` is a straightforward function which keeps track of all 'seen' integers in the first list in the tuple, and all 'duplicates' in the second list.
- `sequence [[0,1] | _ <- c]` generates the Cartesian product of *n* copies of `[0, 1]`, where *n* is the length of the input, i.e. it generates all permutations of 0 and 1 with length *n*.
- `map (sum . zipWith (*) c)` takes the dot product of each of these permutations with the input, which generates all possible sums (plus a stray zero, which is inconsequential, since the input is positive).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>79</s> 75 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)!

```
def f(a,*o):
 for x in a:
  for d in*o,0:o.count(v:=x+d)==1!=print(v);o+=v,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LYwxDoJAEEV7TjFW7MJgWEBUzJ5ASztCQWQJJIQlBBDPYkOjd-I2DmAx-fP-zP_vb_PqCl1P06fvcuc0XzOVQ85StDSPDMh1CyOUNaQEK2VElkY30vuH7uuODZEc7YxLKXayacvF4RdtywH_lc6zKCsF97ZXawlTQ1qxsm76jnHOydpipmNaPt9C03yLRWLEAcIBwaPtjCBcGkGzsIfgr8eQQJCKEOFIghAsDqXWj6Uh2Up_)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 102 bytes

Much longer, but more fun ;) (and much [faster](https://tio.run/##HYtBCoMwEEX3nmI2imKhSZaOc5gutIaUOMyk1ELw6jEtPPjw@I@/adujK0XJIpNp1l3gAB8r/E79MDUgpJ3O89GdnPm/ipxJUDP9PIbawWfzrwWk/sGvIK2bWHxMEKqQOzkMI9lS5BGfS29v1pjhAg))

```
s=1;p=0
for x in input():
 r=s&s<<x&~p|p<<x&~s;p|=r;s|=s<<x;k=0
 while r:
  if r%2:print k
  r/=2;k+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5NboMwEIX3nOJtGjeJo2KTf-MbdNldlFViFEQElg0KkVAv0g2bqlJvxG06hkoevZnn-Wbm68c-61tVyv73Ul0NNBhj302drfZD5rVQVsdRVjm0yEt6tqlf58cITvuZT9N29mk7O6pXttNO-U4HXxXE4XHL7waO-pFncC_yaF1e1ijIcG9aqmKpxf-2OS2OJuDDNSYwpjUXhLMon0C2YotkAvrh_STO0WnNseGQlB04REwhKEItOZLxc0uFIBVbjh0Jxzo4RI0dYcJ5GvoH)

Answer (score 2):

## [SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/), 123 bytes

Golfed vesrion. [Run it on SageMathCell!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNUE1rAjEQvS_sf3h4MaFRGmsVBT16rr0ua4k6keBusiRZaBH_e5OcHBjm8817zJU0NFN86ymO3jZ3aOdxFz2MBdmxJ68iscG7K5NvX677s643qvs29saOR4Hp75TPb2QZP50L9pyRis8vjrQ2F0M2BhYG5QPtDqoLxLnR6Peyrau6MnYY409nQgzYoWlkK9AsBT4FFjndCMj35DJ5aSwEPsp4lSuZErkSWKcgsCythCw7-UqbSLIolUW9cG3rCskGb2xkevJQT8z2eORPPCf8H1VOT9Y=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
def f(a):return[k for k,m in enumerate(prod(1+PolynomialRing(QQ,'x').gen()^b for b in a).coefficients(sparse=False))if m>1]
```

Ungolfed vesrion. [Run it on SageMathCell!](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx9UtFqwjAUfR_sHy7uwZZFWZxzbKAvA2Fv01fREuqNhtakJKlziP--m1RdYWOFkPSce885ae8aJUil11nhEpG-3t4APXfwZlF4BAGVKb-02SlRglV60_BzGMPHlZgTnsxmDLqHbtoUHKhg3t-gTgi4aooyr8sg67cIRKIVnnpB1jr3yuimkIjsgpBMZc064XAPh5XIFEhjIexKg2hpT-kKUTY3KKXKFWrvwMj_rWKxI5O2Z78tkbhKWIfjqSgdtvzefVBEMHu0v30FhbHoa6sjV_T2oqzRxfCfW5Vv_2ixlDN-9KAnNPDGqgjxFkVsLVjTEy6Put7FCElziRSUPLMT4MtL0nOKwgVA6ar2Wamcj6ILvmSwGDJ4YjAIxxcG_IEWpxWBAYPHSI_CG6cDHzF4po3BMELUGWuCyjK6xh8UErbczmNV0QT5RHaO4gS9CRx_5u7USb8B7OfCqg==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)

```
def find_ks(a):
    # Create a polynomial ring
    R = PolynomialRing(QQ, 'x')
    x = R.gen()

    # Calculate the generating function
    gen_function = prod(1 + x^a_i for a_i in a)

    # Find the coefficients of the generating function
    coeffs = gen_function.coefficients(sparse=False)

    # Iterate over the coefficients and return the k-values for which the coefficients are greater than 1
    ks = [k for k, coeff in enumerate(coeffs) if coeff > 1]

    return ks

input_lists = [[1], [4, 5, 2], [9, 10, 11, 12], [2, 3, 5, 6], [15, 16, 7, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

for a in input_lists:
    print(f"{a} -> {find_ks(a)}")
```

Using generating functions. For input \$\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\$, finds all \$k\$s such that the coefficient of \$x^k\$ in \$\prod_{i=1}^n(1+x^{a_i})\$ is greater than \$1\$.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 152 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to `ovs`, -4 bytes thanks to `pxeger`, and -2 bytes thanks to `AndyB`*

Outputs a set of numbers or an empty `set()` if the condition is not met.

```python
lambda s:(r:=range(len(s)))and{T(l)for j in r for l in c(s,j+1)if T(T(k)==T(l)for i in r for k in c(s,i+1))>1}
from itertools import*;c=combinations;T=sum
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=RY9NbsIwEIX3nGKWdmskTCktQeYU2aVZmBC3Q_wT2WZRVb1Iu4mE6J24DXYoYjGaN8_fPNu_f_1n_HB2OCrxdjpENX09_2hptjsJoSC-EF7a95bo1pJAKZV291USTZXzsAe04CFLnWVDAts_cooKSlKSjgpxQ_GOdjcUE0o3_HuivDOAsfXROR0ATe98fFg3onFmi1ZGdDasSxEO5v-FXQ4KOaiqeM2gWjB4ZjDPcsWAz1LxVKMxZ_A0Hi_zxJPgSwYvqTFYjFbaHJmcUtfFBKD3aCNR-cvXK4fh2i8)

Comment: `from itertools import*;c=combinations` saves two bytes and `len([k for ...])` -> `sum(1for ...)`.

Comment: `sum(1for ... if sum(k)==sum(l))` can be `sum(sum(k)==sum(l)for ...)`

Comment: You can save 2 more bytes by writing `from itertools import*;c=combinations;T=sum` and replacing `sum(...)` with `T(...)`.

Comment: @AndyB True, totally missed that. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 12 bytes

```
R@)++JNB\\NB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/V@tpGunZG2tG1uU@D/IQVNb28vPKSbGz@l/aUFtuM//aMNYBUyga6cQHcsVbaKjYKqjYBSLTc5SR8HQAIgNgRiuAiRnZAiUNdJRMAZrNotF1QkUsgDpAqoxBLINzXQUzIGUjoJJLFwNSNAIaLYR0Agjc5BKIA02EOQgZLugQkBrwMYATUZ1FgA)

```
R@     # All subsequences
)++    # Map sum
J      # Dup
NB     # Remove duplicates
\\     # List elements in set A not in B
NB     # Remove duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 106 bytes

```python
g=lambda s:{s}|{q for n in s for q in g(s-{n})}
def f(s):*q,=map(sum,g(s));*map(q.remove,{*q}),;return{*q}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7LDoIwEEX3fEWXLRmN5WWE8CWEBYYWSaSlLZho7bdjx9WcMzdzM@t7e2iVH8fUPoflPg7E1d6FrzdEaksUmRVxfzSIE3UnrwILySgkkdSxOjXQLsNK3b5AjBlrUlRztmLRLwE@NYFBY8W2W4VyYJvDtq7jPXQFlJDFeQN@Ac6Bo2SQx3UViZfAK7gChwINMIknfV8nhKx2VhuVVFr9EcqJDR9gxw8)

Requires a `frozenset` as input.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
æOÐ¢≠ÏÙ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9vc2FiaWX//8OmT8OQwqLiiaDDj8OZ//9bMiwzLDUsNl0) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w8v8D084tOhR54LD/Ydn/tf5Hx1tGKujEG2iY6pjBGJY6hga6Bga6hiCeUY6xkAJMxDT0FTH0EzHXMdQxwTM1QHJAbXFxgIA).

Or alternatively:

```
æO{Åγ≠Ï
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8DL/6sOt5zY/6lxwuP///2gjHWMdUx2zWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w8v8qw@3ntv8qHPB4f7/Ov@jow1jdRSiTXRMdYxADEsdQwMdQ0MdQzDPSMcYKGEGYhqa6hia6ZjrGOqYgLk6IDmgtthYAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
æ        # Get the powerset of the (implicit) input-list
 O       # Sum each inner list
  Ð      # Triplicate it
   ¢     # Pop the top two, and get the counts of each item
    ≠    # Check which counts are NOT 1 (thus >= 2)
     Ï   # Only keep those values from the remaining list
      Ù  # Uniquify it
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)

æO       # Same as above
  {      # Sort them
   Åγ    # Pop and run-length encode this list, pushing the list of values and
         # list of counts as two separated lists
     ≠Ï  # Same as above
         # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
⊇ᶠ+ᵐ{⊇Ċ=}ᶠhᵐd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FX@8NtC7Qfbp1QDWQe6bKtBXIzgNyU//@jDU11DM10zHUMdUxi/0cBAA)

#### Explanation

```
⊇ᶠ               Find all subsets of the input
  +ᵐ             Compute the sum for each of these subsets
    {   }ᶠ       Find all:
     ⊇Ċ=           Subset of 2 elements which are equal
          hᵐ     Get the head of each of these subsets
            d    Remove duplicates (necessary if 3 or more subsets sum to the same number)
```

There are other similar approaches which are also 13 bytes, such as [`⊇ᶠ+ᵐọ{t>1&h}ˢ`](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP9icmFjaHlsb2cy///iiofhtqAr4bWQ4buNe3Q@MSZofcui//9bMTUsMTYsNywxLDRd/1o) or [`⊇ᶠ+ᵍ{l>1&h+}ˢ`](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1FX@8NtC7Qfbu2tzrEzVMvQrj296P//aENTHUMzHXMdQx2T2P9RAA).

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 148 bytes

```
L=[∑_{n=1}^{2^{l.length}-1}bfori=[0...l.total]]
b=\{\total(l\mod(\floor(2n/{2^{[l.\length...1]}}),2))=i,0\}
K=[0...L.\length]\{L>1,0\}
f(l)=K[K>0]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b6jdvu714l)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4yph7pr3ik)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
⊞υ⁰ＦＡＦ⁺υι⊞υκＩΦ⌈υ‹¹№υι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvBCsIwEETvfsUeN7CCWvTSY0EQFHIvPYRSaTBtJJsV/36NLZ3bzHvTjy710QVVKzyiEBxMvXvGBHib35LRGFiaDcJ/7Muwqa@i2uTnjI3jjFcf8pDw4b5@kgnFENwHZjwSNFGKtd5LatW2PRFUBGeCS9fp/hN@) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⁰
```

Start with `0` as the sum of the empty subset of `S`.

```
ＦＡ
```

Loop over the elements of `S`.

```
Ｆ⁺υι⊞υκ
```

Add the element to all of the existing sums and append the results.

```
ＩΦ⌈υ‹¹№υι
```

Output the values that occur more than once.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
à mx ü lÉ câ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=4CBteCD8IGzJIGPi&input=WzIgMyA1IDZdCi1R)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 75 bytes

```sh
for i;a=({$i,}+0$^a)
for s ($a)((++S[s]))
for s ("$S[@]")((++k,s>1))&&<<<$k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYuxCoMwGIT3PMUhQfMTB3@rltKk9B0cxUIWqQi2mE4tffY0cehwHPfd3dvfw6RIhemxYT47qz5yLr@6kjdHIkEPJR0ppXU/@JH@MJP9cB2zvVlKf2GiPDfGyCU8t3l9obDWFiTEBI5q0KKOfgJXYAanUOMQcZcmLbjDEYwmpb2Jl/AD)

Accidentally out-golfed my old [power set implementation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190818/86147), whoops! :)

```sh
for i
    a=({$i,}+0$^a)       # Recursively generate sum strings (e.g.: +0+02+0+04)
for s ($a)
    ((++S[s]))           # Count how many times a sum occurs
for s ("$S[@]")
    ((++k,s>1))&&<<<$k   # If sum $k is bigger than 1, print $k.
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 114 bytes

Using a table variable as input

```sql
WITH D(s,b)as(SELECT*FROM @
UNION ALL SELECT 
S+Q,L
FROM @,D WHERE b<l)SELECT 
s FROM D GROUP BY s HAVING SUM(1)>1
```

**[Try it online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=e98cbd8474daa9eef4012c6c53b3a83a)**

Answer (score 1):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <sup><s>131 129</s></sup> 123 bytes

*saved 2 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)*

```c
*c,i,j;f(*a,n){for(i=n,j=1;i--;)c=calloc(j+=a[i],8);for(i=n*j,*c=1;j;)i?c[i%j+a[i/j]]+=c[--i%j]:c[--j]>1&&printf("%d ",j);}
```

This leaks horribly.
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVJNj5swED3Dr5il2sgG08bp7vbDS/bUXnvsgaLKdSBr1zERIVLbVf566QwEJeqJ8Zs3b96zMbnxOmyHITXCCqcalmoR@EvTdswWQbhCKpvnipvCaO9bw1xW6NJW4j1XZ1LqRGqQ5xS3T6a0ty5DxhtXVVlhyjxHoPpIhavWcrHYdzb0DUtuN5AIx9VpeGWD8cdN/XjoN97@eP28jq8gpG//gza2JWSnbWD8JY5QENA3WBVH5ll3kHobagFp3/6sA3718Re2DvZP/b0HBIzea2P73wJ8HWjofIYCiNQ2DCU5NjQiuyn4zCEYkwOjHdheqm3dU80W09YFLiCPgcNNAZ@@fFZNV9fMcA7oNcKN4xSWowx6wzONKmCjYXLRd1hST0AC30LCuYKJuZxkIjvTPDvHXAqQS7KHzQbYJVRBMSG9zsaJNcbr6imfvlwLZAVcx0ViiQpZViGfLjk6ze7Jxc38pCUkaNPC43it/PLSGEIA/hSoMOrNnQryNYxTpEcWcHBiHPsD9sfOKT4NMr6De1jFHzAiSAlyFa/gLUIPsbwH@QDvQMJdLIFQpP41jdfbw5B/DW1ud3tvMcw/)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 17 bytes

```
(!!1)~<<bg<fo<<ss
```

### Explanation

- `ss` get all subsequences
- `fo` sum them
- `bg` group like elements
- `(!!1)` get the second element from each group

`(!!1)~<<bg` appeared in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/256322/56656) previously as a way to get all elements that appear more than once.

### Reflection

If you click on the linked answer you can see in that answer I said:

> `(!!)` should have a prefix function, and a bunch of versions with the index prefilled. I noticed this earlier but still didn't fix it, and now it's coming back to haunt me.

Well guess what, I *still* haven't fixed it, and it's still losing me bytes.

On top of that the fact that I've used the exact same code `(!!1)~<<bg` now in two different answers is probably a good indicator that it should receive a standalone function.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 58 bytes

```arturo
$=>[powerset&|map=>sum|tally|select[k,v]->v>1|map[k,v]->k]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ensA85)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü÷┬┼╔ª8┐b▼¶╦S╟
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81f6c2c5c9a638bf621f14cb53c7&i=%5B2,3,5,6%5D)

definitely golfable, cant seem to find any way to right now

unpacked:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 16 bytes

```
S{|+mX{x#1=!fu|u
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=S%7B%7C%2BmX%7Bx%231%3D%21fu%7Cu&i=%5B2,3,5,6%5D)

```
S{|+mX{x#1=!fu|u # whole program taking input array S
S                # powerset of S
 {  m            # across this powerset, map...
  |+             # sum
      {     f    # and filter it by
     X x#        # the count of the element in the summed powersets
          =!     # is not equal to
         1       # 1
             u   # uniquify
              |u # uneval, produces string representation of array (no idea if this is required or not, otherwise stax outputs the array as an array of charcodes)
```